# How can i get the calling function name in angular js strict mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have function like this

```
var getData = function(){
console.log('test');
}
```

I call it like  `getData()`

I want to get the name of function inside that.

I tried this

`arguments.callee.caller.toString()`

but i get this error

```
Error: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
```

How can i fix that

Comment: If you call it like this `getData()` don't you already know that function name is `getData`?

Comment: @dfsq actually i have code  which i want to put inside  al functions  which will call the same function in different locations

Comment: You must remove the sentences "use strict" to access that method. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee#Why_was_arguments.callee_removed_from_ES5_strict_mode.3F

Comment: @wZVanG i tried that and then tried console logging and it gave me full function for angular controller rather than getData

Comment: @user3214546 that depends on where you are calling the function in "angular". I think you should put the code "angular"

Comment: You are trying to get the name of **anonymous function**. You can change it into **named function expression** ( `var getData = function getData(){ ... } `) first and get function name by calling `arguments.callee.name`. There quite a lot of ways also [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648293/javascript-get-function-name).