# Getting the name of a variable function expression?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, expression

### The problem

I need to fetch the name of an anonymous function defined as an expression when it is called.

---

### What I've tried so far

In the following example, I am able to `console.log` the name of the function like this:

```
function init() {
    console.log(init.name); // Outputs "init".
}
```

The `console.log` will output `init` respectively. When I define the function as an expression, `console.log(init.name);` will no longer output `init`, because technically I'm asking for the name of an anonymous function (as proven by `console.log(init);` in the second example).

```
var init = function() {
    console.log(init.name); // Outputs nothing.
};
```

The following example will initially solve the problem, as suggested by robertklep:

```
var init = function init() {
    console.log(init.name); // Outputs "init".
};
```

This way, I give the anonymous function a name and I can just fetch the name with `init.name`. Although, this is not the solution I'm looking for.

---

### The question

Is it possible to obtain the name of an anonymous function defined as an expression when it is called at all? Am I forced to give the function a name too if I want to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript get Function Name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648293/javascript-get-function-name)

Comment: It would have been, was it not for the anonymous function expression. Is there a way to get the name of the variable inside the anonymous function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, because coded like that, it's an [*anonymous* function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_(function_expression)) (in other words: it doesn't *have* a name).

But you can give it a name if you like:

```
var init = function theFunctionName() {
  console.log(init.name); // outputs: theFunctionName
};
```

Answer (score 1):

[Anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_(function_expression)) without having any name will give black string if you try `.name`.

```
var init = function() {
  console.log(typeof init.name);// will give blank string 
};
```

But if you give name to function it will give you name.

Answer (score -2):

You can try it like this :

```
console.log(init.toString());
```

Comment: This provides the whole function as a string, not the name of the invoked function.