# JavaScript - Get name by which function has been called

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get string "markHotel" in this code?

```
this.markHotel = this.markPrice = function() {

    // get "markHotel"

};

this.markHotel();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648293/javascript-get-function-name

Comment: @RobM. The issue here is that the function itself is anonymous and has no name.  I'm not sure you can do what the OP is asking here.

Comment: I think the only way you could really do this would be to throw an exception, catch it, and parse the stack which is platform specific and is not obligated to include it. So not really, but well-formed code should not need to anyway.

Comment: If you _really_ need to do this (it looks a bit smelly - is this an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?), you could make `markHotel` and `markPrice` independent functions that call into your anonymous function, passing in the name.

Comment: I think, the answer is "no", unless you have additional control over object.

Comment: I agree with @JamesThorpe - seems like an XY problem. I can't think of a good reason you'd need to do that sort of thing.

Comment: Iside this function I want to place some common code for all functions (markHotel, markPrice and so on) The call of this.markHotel come from outer code. In real code this is someObj.markHotel();

Comment: @holden321 then it is an XY problem. You don't want to get _what was called_ you just need common code. You can have something like `function common() { /* common code */ }` and then something like (effectively) `this.markHotel = function() { common(); /* more code*/ }`. This can also be done with `common` accepting callbacks or functional composition or few other ways. Whatever the case, making the function changed based on how you called it is a code smell.

Comment: This is what I am trying to avoid, repeating common() in each function. I want something like functionname(); inside common code.

Comment: `function makeMarkFunction(callback) {  return function() {/* common code */; callback()} }` and then `this.markHotel = makeMarkFunction(function() {/* markHotel specific stuff */})`. It keeps your things nice and generic, you don't need to care what calls your function. You _shouldn't_ need to care what calls it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Function.prototype.bind().  Here's a simple example:

```
function base() {
  console.log(this.name);

  // do some other stuff using this.name or other this props...
}

var markPrice = base.bind({ name: 'markPrice' });

var markHotel = base.bind({ name: 'markHotel' });

// this will log 'markPrice'
markPrice();

// this will log 'markHotel'
markHotel();
```

It looks like you may be doing this inside a class constructor, but it's not totally clear from your example.  If that's the case, make sure not to confuse the class constructor's "this" context and the "base" function's "this" context, the latter being manually bound when setting markPrice and markHotel.

Docs for bind: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Here's a pen: http://codepen.io/bsidelinger912/pen/QKLvzL