# How to get the function name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a `ajax` function which will call a function if its `error` and this error will call a function which displays the error message. here is the code

```
function Update_uam() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "IROA_StoredProcedures.asmx/update_uam1",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            console.log(tbody);
        },
        error: errorHandler
    });
}

function errorHandler(XMLHttpRequest) {
    console.log(errorHandler.caller.caller);
    console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
}
```

I tried several ways but seems to failed. What I want to do is also displays which function the error comes from for easy debugging.

Comment: What I want to do is also displays which function the error comes from for easy debugging? i got this: ƒ (a,c){return e||(c=c||[],c=[a,c.slice?c.slice():c],g.push(c),b||i()),this}

Comment: Ever heard of a "stack trace"?

Comment: *"What I want to do is also displays which function the error comes from for easy debugging."* - No. What you want to do is learn how to set breakpoints, use the debugger in the browser's developer tools and how the call stack that it shows you works.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648293/how-to-get-the-function-name-from-within-that-function

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use :

```
function Update_uam() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "IROA_StoredProcedures.asmx/update_uam1",
        data: "",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function () {
            console.log(tbody);
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
            var msg = '';
            if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
            } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
            }
            $('#post').html(msg);
        },
    });
```

Comment: Your answer is not wrong, though it does not meet the requested requirements. The user was asking to get the function-name where the error came from.

Comment: This is not wrong but the purpose of the function so the code will be re-usable.