# How to print only the `this` object's name , and not it's contents in javascript?

Tags: javascript

consider the function:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this);
}

foo();
```

How to print only the `this` object's name (window or global....etc), and not it's contents?

Comment: in sloppy mode, you can assume that `this` is an object, so `this.constructor.name` should always work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the function name from within that function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648293/how-to-get-the-function-name-from-within-that-function)

Comment: no, i am asking for `this` object's name, not the function's name

Comment: What's the purpose?

Comment: There is no reverse mapping in the sense of reference to variable name, plus objects may be anonymous or have multiple "names".

Comment: I want to debug a code and i am printing `this` in many places, and using console.log , it is just impossible to distinguish in node.js output in terminal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can print an objects name in js with `obj.constructor.name`.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this.constructor.name)
}

foo()
```

Will print `Window`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this.constructor.name`:

```js
function foo() {
  console.log(this.constructor.name);
}

foo();
```

Answer (score 2):

by constructor name. `console.log(this.constructor.name)`