# Log function name without outputting its content

Tags: javascript

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
function caller( _func_to_call , param){

       console.log( ` @@@>  CALLING  ${_func_to_call.toString()} `); 
       _func_to_call(param);
}
```

In this line:

```
 console.log( ` @@@>  CALLING  ${_func_to_call.toString()} `);
```

I want to output the name of the function that its going to be called, but it's logging all the function with its content, like this:

```
 @@@>  CALLING  async function start_transaction(transaction){

    update_transaction_date(transaction);

    var tab_id = `transaction-${transaction.id}`;
    console.log(`----> START TRANSACTION ${tab_id}`);
    ...
```

How can I get it to only output `start_transaction`?

Comment: This question could be ommited by just googling "function name js"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the function name from within that function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648293/how-to-get-the-function-name-from-within-that-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a function property called name.
_func_to_call.name

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [`Function.prototype.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name). You can use it like this:

```
console.log(` @@@>  CALLING  ${_func_to_call.name} `);
```

Now since you're logging always the same function name it doesn't make much sense, but in general you can log any function name using the `.name` attribute. Here's an example:

```
function logFuncName(func) {
    console.log(func.name);
}

logFuncName(function foo() {});
```

Output:

```
foo
```

Answer (score 3):

To get a function's name you have to get the `name` property, so in your case `_func_to_call.name`.

[Function.prototype.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)