# Get the name of a function on the prototype?

Tags: javascript

How can I access the name of a running function that is attached to a prototype?

See my best attempt below. It outputs an empty string.

```
Client.prototype.setAllMain = function() {
    console.log(this.setAllMain.name);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648293/how-to-get-the-function-name-from-within-that-function

Comment: If the function is not anonymous, `.name` should work. setAllMain is written as an anonymous function though and will not have a name. Why do you need the function name though? Since needing the function name at runtime is usually a sign of other problems

Comment: What is `this.getArcs`?

Comment: @Shilly a hackish way would be to throw error and loop through stacktrace to get first named function. However, it will be an ugly way

Comment: @Bergi: It was a typo, fixed now

Comment: I'd prefer `Client.prototype.setAllMain = function setAllMain () { ... };`, so that it has a proper name and .name will work. Seems more sensible than parsing a stack trace or using arguments.calle, which won't work in strict mode.

Comment: @user1283776 Ah ok. But I don't get it, if you know that you want to get the property name of `this.setAllMain`, why not just write `"setAllMain"`?

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks for asking. I must admit that there was no good reason really. I just couldn't figure out why my various attempts were not working and wanted to understand what was wrong. I think Shilly solved the problem.