# Does javascript function know its name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function called getItem. I want to read the name of this function using code from within it. Is this possible?

```
function getItem(){ 
   var functionName =   //how do I read the function name;
   alert(functionName)  //outputs 'getItem'
}
```

Comment: Who says a function even has to have a name? After all, javascript has great support for un-named functions.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn, I know what you mean, but this function has a name because I made sure to give it one. Is there a way to get that name from within the function?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Are you writing a testing framework and injecting this code into other functions? There might be  a way to solve your problem without requiring the name of a function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I get the name of the currently running function in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get the name of the currently running function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
function getItem(){ 
   var functionName =   arguments.callee.name;
   alert(functionName)  //outputs 'getItem'
}
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/xGzKA/

also see this [previous stack Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript) for another solution

Comment: arguments.callee is deprecated in strict JS, just as a point of note.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, in IE you have to use the solution in the other stack Q

Comment: @Neal you better add this to the answer then. IE8 still has fair share.. :)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard its already there. i show the other solutions local :-P

Comment: @Neal: I mean add something like "this code does not work on IE browsers, see the other solution" as people (myself included) assume the code you posted is cross browser.

Comment: @DDavies maybe you can explain me then this phrase from MDC: "JavaScript 1.4: Deprecated callee as a property of Function.arguments, retained it as a property of a function's local arguments variable." (not trying to be a d**k here, I truly don't understand in which situations is deprecated and in which is not)

Comment: @Aleadam it's deprecated as a property of the Function prototype, retained otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Though you should probably not use this, you can do this for IE, Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera (I admit `arguments.callee` is convenient despite the valid reservations expressed about it, as would be `arguments.callee.name` if the Function.name property were standard):

```
function getFuncName (fn) {
    var name = (/\W*function\s+([\w\$]+)\s*\(/).exec(fn);
    return name ? name[1] : '(Anonymous)';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
function getItem(){
    var functionName =  arguments.callee.name;
    alert(functionName);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XPGxE/

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript

Comment: @Neal Didnt mean to copy. I posted the same answer almost the same time as you. Saw your answer only after posting.