# Get function name from inside itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

let's say I have a function:

```
 function test1() {

       }
```

I want to return "test1" from within itself. I found out that you can do `arguments.callee` which is going to return the whole function and then do some ugly regex. Any better way?

what about namespaced functions?

is it possible to get their name as well:
e.g.:

```
var test2 = 
{
 foo: function() {
    }
};
```

I want to return foo for this example from within itself.

**update:** for arguments.callee.name Chrome returns blank, IE9 returns undefined. and it does not work with scoped functions.

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648293/javascript-get-function-name

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does javascript function know its name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5599513/does-javascript-function-know-its-name) and [Get function name in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3178892/218196).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the function name from within that function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648293/how-to-get-the-function-name-from-within-that-function)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var test2 = {
   foo: function() {
   }
};
```

You aren't giving the function a name.  You are assigning the `foo` property of `test2` to an anonymous function.

`arguments.callee.name` only works when functions are declared using the `function foo(){}` syntax.

This should work:

```
var test2 = {
   foo: function foo() {
      console.log(arguments.callee.name); // "foo"
   }
};
```

Comment: It's worth noting `arguments.callee` and `arguments.caller` are being deprecated.

Comment: And note that when the function runs it doesn't know that it "belongs" to `test2`. (Because it doesn't "belong", it is just that `test2` happens to have a property `foo` that references the function; you could create other references to the same function. Depending on how you call it it _may_ have a `this` reference to that object.)

Comment: Fails in IE 8 and lower, here's a good examination of [named function expressions](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/) and why they aren't a good idea.