# How can I execute recursion regardless of the function name?

Tags: javascript, function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get the name of the currently running function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

I need this for recursion. I'd like to be able to change the function name without checking and changing every instance where the function calls itself.

(For example php has "magic constants" like `__FUNCTION__` etc.. - is something similar in JavaScript?)

Comment: there's already an answer to this question... [See Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Actually this question is slightly different, since he wants a reference to the function and not really the name.  The name alone does not help him for recursive calls... Hence: No **exact duplicate**.

Comment: @Ferdinand Agreed. "alert the name of the function" and "have the function call itself without using its name at all" are quite different problems. +1 to your answer as well; I actually prefer it to my own :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your goal is **recursion**, you don't need the **function name** as a string if you can get a **reference to the function itself**. Note that you'll still have to check and change every instance where the function is called by others, and that's likely to be a larger task than updating the recursive calls (if for no other reason than it's not localized to the function body).

**Passing the function as an argument**

```
function foo(self, i)
{
    if (i === 0 )
        return;

    console.log(i--);
    self(self, i);
}

foo(foo, 3);
```

**Using arguments.callee** (As Raynos points out, this is brittle in strict mode)

```
function foo(i)
{
    if (i === 0 )
        return;

    console.log(i--);
    arguments.callee(i);
}

foo(3);
```

**Output of either option**

```
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can refactor your function since `arguments.callee` is not dependable.  For example, you could use a nested function that does the recursion:

```
var name_does_not_matter = function(m) {
    var inner = function(n) {
        if (n <= 2) return 1;
        return inner(n-2) + inner(n-1);
    };
    return inner(m);
};
```

---

[**UPDATE**] Actually, you should be able to access the function by its name regardless of the parent scope.  In my test, the following example works:

```
var foo = 10;
var bar = function foo(n) {
    return (n <= 2) ? 1 : foo(n-2) + foo(n-1);
};
alert(foo);  // Displays '10'
alert(bar(10));  // Displays '55'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function senad()
{
  var fName= arguments.callee.toString();
            fName= fName.substr('function '.length);       
            fName= fName.substr(0, fName.indexOf('('));  
            alert(fName)
}
senad();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() { 
  "use strict"; 
  console.log(arguments.callee); 
})()
```

Yields

`TypeError: Cannot access property 'callee' of strict mode arguments`

You cannot do this in ES5 strict mode, and for a good reason. It's a hack. Don't do it.