# is it possible to get function name in which given closure is running?

Tags: javascript

```
function MyFunction() {
  closure = function() {
    alert('my parent function name is: '/* now what here ? */);
  }
  closure();
}
MyFunction();
```

Result should be `my parent function name is: MyFunction`

(To moderators: I do not know why stackoverflow is preventing me from sending this question claiming it doesn't meet quality standards. Do I must type some superfluous text to be allowed to send this.)

Comment: Just typing some code without including a question is definitely not up to SO standards, no. I see you put your question into the subject line, but that's not enough.

Comment: take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648293/javascript-get-function-name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/280389/how-do-you-find-out-the-caller-function-in-javascript maybe dublicate

Comment: And another : [Can I get the name of the currently running function in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

Comment: It's worth noting that you can also just do `MyFunction.name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is/*was* possible, but it is restricted. First restriction, not all Javascript engines support the following pattern and second (more dramatic), *ES5 strict mode* does not support it either.

Some Javascript engines allow you to access the `.__parent__` property which is a reference to the parent scope. That should look like

```
alert('my parent is ' + this.__parent__.name );
```

where you would have to call `new closure()`, or give the function a name and use that name instead of `this`.

However, most implementations removed that access for security concerns. As you may noticed, you're able to breach the 'allmighty' closure security by beeing able to access the parent context.

---

Another way to accomplish it, is to access `arguments.callee.caller`, which also is not accessible in *ES5 strict mode*. Looks like:

```
function MyFunction() {
  closure = function f() {
    alert('my parent function name is: ' +  arguments.callee.caller.name);
  }
 closure();
}
MyFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function MyFunction() {
  closure = function() {
    alert('my parent function name is: ' + arguments.callee.caller.name);
  }
  closure();
}
MyFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function MyFunction() {
    var functionName = arguments.callee.name,
    closure = function() {
        alert('my parent function name is: ' + functionName);
    }
    closure();
}
MyFunction();
```

Comment: After thinking more about it: This gives you the name of the function where the closure is *defined* in, not where it is *run* (though in this special case it does).

Comment: He's looking for the closure, not the parent object. That you can get with `this`. You might also be interested in `arguments.caller` and `Function.caller`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/caller

Comment: The closure is defined by where the function is *defined*, **not** by where it is *run*!

Comment: Yes, I know. The question was *"is it possible to get function name in which given closure is **running**"*. Your code only works if the closure is run in the same function it was defined. That's all I wanted to say.

Comment: In that case, I don't even understand the question. What does it mean *in which given closure is running*? That is what the `this` keyword is used for! What am I missing?

Comment: Imagine a function that returns a closure. Now I have `function A() { var c = getClosure(); c();}; A();`. How would the closure get the name `A` here? (btw. the other answers show how). `this` most likely refers to `window` if the function is not called as `object` method.