# get var name from this or self reference javascript

Tags: javascript

I see that there are some other questions that seem to be on a similar topic but none have an answer that will help me with my particular problem. I have made a thread library in in JavaScript built around the `setTimeout` and `setInterval` functions.  This is working very well except that my thread library requires that the name of thread is past to the thread i.e when I instantiate the thread it looks like this.

```
t = new Thread(payload, "t")
```

payload is an object that defines the what the thread will do when it gets a chance to execute. This allows me to abstract the task of the thread from the underlying threads "plumbing".  In any case my problem that I have to pass name of thread because `setTimeout` and `setInterval` take a JavaScript command as a string i.e `setTimeout("doStuff", 0)`.  As I use my thread library in more applications passing the name to the thread is becoming more of a pain.  So I would like to be able to avoid this by getting the name of the thread from within the thread class like this:

```
var myThreadName = this.someMagicFunction();
```

or

```
var myThreadName = someMagicFunction(this);
```

or some other fantastic method if anyone has any ideas for me I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, both can take a function as the first parameter, and this is the recommended usage (since the string versions do an `eval`).

```
setTimeout(doStuff, 0);
```

In your case, you might be able to do something like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  t.payload();
}, 0);
```

depending how the Thread object looks.

See the MDC documentation ([setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setTimeout), [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval)).

Comment: thanks for the help it worked like a charm.  I was running into trouble before because I was doing setTimeout(doStuff(),1).  Passing the function by name works perfectly. Once again thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function to `setTimeout` as long as it is argument-free, i.e.

```
function takeme()
{
    alert('workin?');
}

setTimeout(takeme, 100);
```

and if it is not, then you can try

```
function takeme(x)
{
    alert(x);
}
var test = 1;
setTimeout(function(){ takeme(test); }, 100);
```

But if you really need to extract a function name, then please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript). Not exactly the same, but somewhat related.