# can the HTML5 Canvas element be created from the Canvas constructor

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I would like to be able to make Canvas elements from the constructor so that I could make a function like this.

```
function createCanvasContext(height,width)
{
   var body =  document.getElementsById('body')[0];
   var canvas = new Canvas();
   canvas.height=height;
   canvas.width = width;
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   body.appendChild(canvas);
   return context;
}
```

I get an error at the line var canvas = new Canvas() saying that 'Canvas is undefined' does HTML5 not allow creating elements from the constructor? or are there parameters that I need to pass to the constructor.  Any ideas would be great.

Comment: There is no Canvas constructor. If you want to ceate a new `<canvas>` element, use `var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");`. *PS. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7858231/938089) seems to solve your previous question. Use the [Accept answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/169101) feature to mark the answer as the right one.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

While you can do `new Image()` just fine, `new Canvas()` isn't a thing! `Canvas` Isn't even a thing, though `HTMLCanvasElement` is. Nonetheless you cannot use its constructor.

```
document.createElement('canvas');
```

is what you want. You have to use that, just like with `div`s.

Answer (score 67):

```
var mycanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
mycanvas.id = "mycanvas";
document.body.appendChild(mycanvas);
```

Comment: This is more complete answer!

Comment: why set an id if you created the element yourself ? for the css ? and, in many cases you want to create a canvas, but not add it to the DOM anyway.

Comment: Simple info: in a document, an ID must be used for only one element.

Comment: To be clear, you do _not_ have to append the canvas to the DOM if you are just using it to generate an image (to render onto another canvas, for example)

Comment: Thanks @aboveyou00, that's a very helpful distinction to make! I wish your comment was the selected answer!

Comment: How then is the **canvas constructor** (https://archive.is/CWkv9#selection-2507.3-2507.22) done?

Comment: @Pacerier I think they just mean the DOM-Element constructor which you can't use in JavaScript directly.