# Get CurrentMethodName in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get the name of the currently running function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

In Javascript Is there a way I can get the name of the method/ function inside which the javascript is getting executed. 
I want

> alert('This message is coming while running inside the method ' + GetCurrentMethodName());

Answer (score 1):

Use `arguments.callee.name` like this:

```
alert('This message is coming while running inside the method ' + arguments.callee.name);
```

Comment: Won't work with anonymous function assigned to method

Comment: That's because anonymous functions don't have names...

Comment: Then, this will just return an empty string.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: Exactly. :)

Comment: sure, but I think the OP wants the *method label* (someobj.NAME would be NAME for example)

Comment: @KooiInc: OP asked for "method/function". He's clearly coming from a non JS context where functions are called methods. :)

Comment: Hi, I am getting "undefined" on arguments.callee.name. how do I get the proper method name?