# Get function name from function itself

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I get the name of the currently running function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

I want to get the function name from function itself.

Javascript:

```
Cube : {
    profile : {
        edit : function(){
            // Get function Path Cube.edit Here
            alert(arguments.callee.name); // Not Working
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could just name your function: `edit: function edit() { ... }`

Comment: @Osiris I goes through this question. but i didn't get my answer. `alert(arguments.callee.name);` not working for above example of code.

Comment: @elclanrs: That creates [two functions](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) on IE8 and earlier.

Comment: @elclanrs I edit my code in Question. Please take look. Now i want to get profile.edit()

Comment: @JavedAkhtar: Changing the code just adding a further object layer is pointless, it doesn't change the question at all, just makes the existing answers look weird until they're edited.

Answer (score 8):

The function in your code snippet *has* no name, it's anonymous. The property it's assigned to on `profile` has a name (`edit`), but the function does not. No, there is no way to get `edit` or `profile.edit` or `Cube.profile.edit` from the function object.

You can give the function a name:

```
Cube : {

   profile: {
       edit : function edit(){

         alert(arguments.callee.name);

       }
   }
}
```

...but that's using a *named function expression* which will create [two separate function objects](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html) on IE8 and earlier.

You can also do this:

```
Cube : {

   profile: {
       edit : Cube_profile_edit
    }
}
// ...

function Cube_profile_edit(){

    alert(arguments.callee.name);
}
```

However, in all of the above, two problems:

1. You're using `arguments.callee` which is both very slow on a lot of browsers, and not valid in [strict mode](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-C).
2. The `name` property of function objects is non-standard, which is why [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript) talks about possibly having to parse the result of `Function#toString`. The problem is, `Function#toString` is **also** non-standard (but fairly broadly supported, except on mobile browsers).

You could avoid that second problem by searching through the `Cube` object graph for the property that refers to the function, but that would still require using `arguments.callee` (unless you give the function a real name and then use that real name when searching to find the property path that leads to it).