# Obtaining the name of the current function being executed in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In Node.js, I'm trying to obtain the name of current function being executed:

```
function doSomething(req, res) {
  console.log('Function name: ' + doSomething.name);
}
```

This works well, but I'd like (if possible) to obtain the name within the current context. This way, if I renamed the method later I don't have change it manually. Is there a generic object (i.e. similar to 'this') that points to the current function being executed/current context? Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript get Function Name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648293/javascript-get-function-name)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript

Comment: I don't think is a dupe. Seems that all examples require the actual function (in this case, I'd rather use 'doSomething.name'). The other answer doesn't work because 'arguments.callee' is not allowed under strict mode.

Comment: It's not allowed in strict mode because it's deprecated and it's an unusual request to **need** the function's name; there's rarely a good use case for it. Can you explain your reason for getting the name?

Comment: Sure: logging and profiling the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get the name of the currently running function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Not all functions *have* a name.  Ex:  `(a, b) => a + b;`

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: `Object.values(this)[0].name`

Long Answer:

`let myInstanceArray = Object.values(this)` Enumerates the object properties as an array

`let myInstance = myInstanceArray[0]` Gets the first, and only, item in the array

`let myName = myInstance.name` Gets the name of the item.

Comment: arguments.callee.name working, the other one is NOT working.

Comment: Note: arguments.callee.name does not work in "strict" mode

Comment: callee seems deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to repeat the answers in the "possible duplicate" suggestions from Ian, but there is a solution that might be worth mentioning in addition to them:

You could use a named function expression, to have one name, that is accessible from outside of the function and one name that is accessible from inside:

```
var x = function y() {
    console.log(y);
};

console.log(x);
```

Now, if you decide to give your function a different name, you can just change `x` while still be able to refer to the function by using `y`.

Comment: Uf. But this is so cumbersome! That would mean implementing all function this way. It may work, but it's a real pain, especially in large apps. :-/

Comment: That's why I said "in addition" ;) Honestly, I wouldn't use it, but I also wouldn't use any of the other methods. If I would decide to change the name of a function, I would just change it everywhere in my code.

Comment: @titusmagnus MDN suggests it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee#Description

Comment: @titusmagnus by the way: asaik you can use the same "internal" name for every function. So you can just write `var myFunc = function callee() {}` for every function and can now use `callee` everywhere to access the current function.

Comment: Ian, with all due respect to MDN, their suggestion may apply to some apps, not all of them. For some large existing apps, this would require a major re-implementation. Thanks, but no thanks ;-)

Comment: @basilikum I'm not sure I follow. Sounds interesting. Could you please post a small snippet so I can see what you mean?

Comment: @titusmagnus sure: http://jsfiddle.net/AWSxh/ but be aware that I'm not entirely sure that this doesn't cause any sideeffect. But since the "internal" name isn't accessible from outside the function, I think you should be fine.

Comment: @basilikum Unfortunately, the named function leaks into the outer (not global) scope in IE (maybe just old IE). Otherwise it should be fine. http://kangax.github.io/nfe/

Comment: @titusmagnus I was just pointing out that MDN suggested the approach instead of the unstable/unsupported `arguments.callee`. And if you actually **need** to know the name of the current function, you just might need a major re-implementation anyways because I really can't see a reason for knowing it

Comment: @Ian ok, I suspected there to be a hitch somewhere. Good to know!

Comment: @Ian, I know, I know ;-) Thanks for the help, Ian.

Comment: This is what I find confusing about JS. It *may* work in some environments, but not others. This is why I mentioned Node.js in the title. I was hoping to discover a solution for Node, even if it doesn't work in any other environment. I'm willing to accept this limitation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use property `name` as:

```
const yourFunction = () => {};

console.log(yourFunction.name);
// output: "yourFunction"
```

[MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)