# Does Chrome retain each object's constructor?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, constructor, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome's JavaScript console:

```
> function create(proto) {
    function Created() {}
    Created.prototype = proto
    return new Created
  }
undefined

> cc = create()
Created {}

> cc
Created {}
```

`Created` is a function private to the `create` function; after `create` completes, there are no (known to me) references to `Created`. Yet Chrome can show the function's name at any time, starting from the object created by it.

Chrome didn't achieve this by following the "naïve" approach:

```
> cc.constructor
function Object() { [native code] }

> cc.toString()
"object [Object]"
```

and anyway, I didn't set `constructor` on the `proto` argument passed to `create`:

```
> cc.__proto__.hasOwnProperty("constructor")
false
```

One guess I had is that the JavaScript VM holds on to `Created` for the sake of the `instanceof` mechanism. It is said that [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2Finstanceof)

> tests whether an object has in its prototype chain the prototype property of a constructor.

But in the above code I typed `create()`, effectively passing `undefined` as prototype; consequently `Created` doesn't even have its `prototype` set to the actual `cc.__proto__`. We can verify this if we hack `create` to expose the `Created` function:

```
function create(proto) {
  function Created() {}
  Created.prototype = proto
  GlobalCreated = Created
  return new Created
}
```

now let's type

```
> cc = create()
Created {}

> GlobalCreated
function Created() {}

> GlobalCreated.prototype
undefined

> cc instanceof GlobalCreated
TypeError: Function has non-object prototype 'undefined' in instanceof check
```

### My questions (all closely related):

1. What exactly does Chrome's JavaScript engine retain to make that object presentation in the console work? Is it the constructor function, or just the function name?
2. Is that retention needed for anything more substantial than console printout?
3. What is the effect of such retention on memory consumption? What if, for example, the constructor function (or even its name) is abnormally huge?
4. Is it just Chrome? I've retested with Firebug and Safari, their consoles don't present the object that way. But do they still retain the same data, for other possible purposes (e.g. due to a genuine concern inherent to a JavaScript VM)?

Comment: Hope you'll be more lucky than me : http://stackoverflow.com/q/21014020/1636522 :)

Comment: @wared In your question, did you focus on getting the *name* of a function you already have, or getting the *constructor* which created an arbitrary object, having access only to that object? As I read it, it is the former, whereas my concern is the latter.

Comment: Indeed, you're right, I had misread the first part of your question :/

Comment: @wared Since your comment I have rephrased the question title to make my pivotal concern more obvious.

Comment: looks like it's using ES's internal [[Class]] to display the instance in the console.

Answer (score 13):

### Late edit:

I recently revisited this question/answer, and I *think* I've figured out why chrome seems to *"hang on"* to the `Created` name. It's not really something that is exclusive to V8, but I think it's the result of how V8 works behind the scenes (the hidden objects I explained in my initial answer), and what V8 is required to do (to conform to the ECMAScript standard).

Any function, constructor functions or otherwise, share the same constructor and prototype-chain by default:

```
function Created(){};
console.log(Created.constructor);//function Function() { [native code] }
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Created));//function Empty() {}
console.log(Created.__proto__);//same as above
console.log(Created.prototype);//Created {}
```

This tells us a few things: All functions share the native `Function` constructor, and inherit from a specific function instance (`function Empty(){}`) that is used as their prototype. However, a function's `prototype` property is required to be an object, that the function would return if it were called as a constructor (see [ECMAScript standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.5.2)).

> The value of the prototype property is used to initialise the [[Prototype]] internal property of a newly created object before the Function object is invoked as a constructor for that newly created object. This property has the attribute { [[Writable]]: true, [[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }.

We can verify this easily by looking at the `Created.prototype.constructor`:

```
console.log(Created.prototype.constructor);//function Created() {}
```

Now let's, for a moment, list the hidden classes V8 needs to, and probably will, create in order for it to comply to the standard:

```
function Created(){}
```

Hidden classes:

- `Object`, of course: the mother of all objects, of which `Function` is a specific child
- `Function`: This native object is, as we've demonstrated, the constructor
- `function Empty`: The prototype, from which our function will inherit
- `Created` our empty function that will inherit from all of the above

At this stage, nothing unusual has happened, and it's self-evident that, when we return an instance of *this* `Created` constructor, the `Created` function will get exposed because of its prototype.
Now, because we're reassigning the `prototype` property you could argue that this instance will be discarded, and is lost, but from what I understand, that's not how V8 will handle this situation. Instead, it'll create an additional hidden class, that simply overrides the `prototype` property of its parent after this statement is encountered:

Created.prototype = proto;

Its internal structure will end up looking something like this (numbered this time, because I'll refer back to certain stages within this inheritance chain further down):

1. `Object`, of course: the mother of all objects, of which `Function` is a specific child
2. `Function`: This native object is, as we've demonstrated, the constructor
3. `function Empty`: The prototype, from which our function will inherit
4. `Created` our empty function that will inherit from all of the above
5. `Created2`: extends the previous class (`Created`), and overrides `prototype`

## So why is `Created` still visible?

That's the million dollar question, to which I think I have the answer now: ***Optimization***

V8 simply can't, nor should it be allowed to, optimize out the `Created` hidden class (stage 4). Why? Because what will override `prototype` is an argument. It's something that can't be predicted. What V8 will probably do to optimize the code is to store a hidden object 4, and whenever the `create` function is called, it'll create a new hidden class that extends stage 4, overriding the `prototype` property with whatever value is passed to the function.

Because of this, `Created.prototype` will always exist somewhere inside each instance's internal representation. It's also important to note you could replace the `prototype` property with one that actually referenced an instance of `Created` (with a mucked-up prototype chain, but still):

```
cc = create();
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(cc))//Object {}
cc = create(new GlobalCreated);
console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(cc));//Created {}
```

How's that for a mind-bender? Inception script-writers, eat your hearts out...

Anyway, I hope all of this dribble made some sense to someone out here, if not, I do respond to comments, so corrections to mistakes I may have made, or questions regarding some part of this update that is a bit unclear are welcome...

---

I'll try to answer question by question, but as you say, they're all closely related, so the answers overlap up to a point.
While reading this, bare in mind that I wrote this in one go, whilst feeling a bit feverish. I am not a V8 expert, and based this on recollections of my doing some digging in the V8 internals some time ago. The link at the bottom is to the official docs, and will of course contain more accurate and up-to-date information on the subject.

***What is going on***
What chrome's V8 engine *actually* does is create a hidden class for each object, and this class is mapped to the JS representation of the object.
Or as the people at google say so themselves:

> To reduce the time required to access JavaScript properties, V8 does not use dynamic lookup to access properties. Instead, V8 dynamically creates hidden classes behind the scenes.

What happens in your case, extending, creating a new constructor from a particular instance and overriding the `constructor` property is actually nothing more than what you can see on this graph:

[image: Google inheritance graph]

Where hidden class C0 could be regarded as the standard `Object` class. Basically, V8 interprets your code, builds a set of C++ like classes, and creates an instance if needed. The JS objects you have are set to point to the different instances whenever you change/add a property.

In your `create` function, this is -very likely- what is going on:

```
function create(proto)
{//^ creates a new instance of the Function class -> cf 1 in list below
    function Created(){};//<- new instance of Created hidden class, which extends Function cf 2
    function Created.prototype = proto;//<- assigns property to Created instance
    return new Created;//<- create new instance, cf 3 for details
}
```

1. Right: `Function` is a native construct. The way V8 works means that there is a Function class that is referenced by all functions. They reference this class indirectly, though, because each function has its own specifcs, which are specified in a derived hidden class. `create`, then, should be seen as a reference to `create extends HiddenFunction` class.
   Or, if you wish, in C++ syntax: `class create : public Hidden::Function{/*specifics here*/}`
2. The `Create` function references a hidden function identical to `create`. However, after declaring it, the class receives 1 propriety property, called `prototype`, so another hidden class is created, specifying this property. This is the basis of your constructor. Because the function body of `create`, where all of this happens, this is a given, and V8 will probably be clever enough to create these classes beforehand, anyway: in C++ pseudo-code, it'll look similar to code listing 1 below.
   Each function call will assign a reference to a new instance Of the hidden class described above, to the `Created` name, which is local to `create`'s scope. Of course, the returned instance of `create` does still retain the reference to this instance, but that's how JS scopes work, and so this applies to all engines... think of closures and you'll get what I mean (I'm really struggling with this nasty fever... sorry to nag about this)
3. At this stage `Create` points to an instance of this hidden class, which extends a class that extends a class (as I tried to explain in point 2). Using the `new` keyword triggers behaviour defined by the `Function` class, of course (as it's a JS language construct). This results in a hidden class to be created which is probably the same for all instances: it extends the native object, and this has a `constructor` property, which references the instance of `Created` we've just made. The instances returned by `create` though are all alike. Sure their constructors may have a different `prototype` property, but the objects they churn out all look the same. I'm fairly confident that V8 will only create 1 hidden class for the objects `create` returns. I can't see why the instances should require different hidden classes: their property names & count are the same, but each instance references another instance, but that's what classes are for

Anyway: code listing for item 2, a pseudo-code representation of what `Created` might look like in hidden-class terms:

```
//What a basic Function implementation might look like
namespace Hidden
{//"native" JS types
    class Function : public Object
    {
        //implement new keyword for constructors, differs from Object
        public:
            Function(...);//constructor, function body etc...
            Object * operator new ( const Function &);//JS references are more like pointers
            int length;//functions have a magic length property
            std::string name;
    }
}
namespace Script
{//here we create classes for current script
    class H_create : public Hidden::Function
    {};
    class H_Created : public Hidden::Function
    {};//just a function
    class H_Created_with_prototype : public H_Created
    {//after declaring/creating a Created function, we add a property
     //so V8 will create a hidden class. Optimizations may result in this class
     // being the only one created, leaving out the H_Created class
        public: 
            Hidden::Object prototype;
    }
    class H_create_returnVal : public Hidden::Object
    {
        public:
            //the constructor receives the instance used as constructor
            //which may be different for each instance of this value
            H_create_returnVal(H_Created_with_prototype &use_proto);
    }
}
```

Ignore any (likely) syntax oddities (it's been over a year since I wrote a line of C++), and ignoring namespaces and wacky names, The listed classes are, apart from the `Hidden::Function` effectively all the hidden classes that will ever need to be created to run your code. All your code then does is assign references to instances of these classes. The classes themselves don't take up much space in memory. And any other engine will create just as many objects, because they, too, need to comply with the ECMAScript specs.
So I guess, looking at it like this, this sort of answers all your questions: no not all engines work like this, but this approach won't cause massive amounts of memory to be used, Yes, this does mean a lot of information/data/references to all objects is retained, but that's just an unavoidable, and in some cases happy side-effect of this approach.
***Update***: I did a bit more digging, and found an example of how you could add JS functions to V8 using templates, it illustrates how V8 translates JS objects/functions to C++ classes, [see the example here](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed#templates)

This is just me speculating, but I wouldn't at all be surprized to learn that the way V8 works, and this retention business is heavily used in garbage-collection and memory management in general (EG: deleting a property changing hidden classes and the like)
For example:

```
var foo = {};//foo points to hidden class Object instance (call id C0)
foo.bar = 123;//foo points to child of Object, which has a property bar (C1)
foo.zar = 'new';//foo points to child of C1, with property zar (C2)
delete foo.zar;//C2 level is no longer required, foo points to C1 again
```

That last bit is just me guessing, but it *could* be possible for the GC to do this.

***What is this retention used for***
As I said, in V8, a JS object is actually a sort-of pointer to a C++ class. Accessing properties (and this includes the magic properties of arrays, too!), is fast. Really, really fast. In theory, accessing a property is an *O(1)* operation.
That's why, on IE:

```
var i,j;
for(i=0,j=arr.length;i<j;++i) arr[i] += j;
```

Is faster than:

```
for (i=0;i<arr.length;++i) arr[i] += arr.length;
```

While on chrome, `arr.length` is faster [as shown her](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32186/why-is-this-code-so-much-faster-relatively-in-ie7/32233). I also answered that question, and it, too, contains some details on V8 you may want to check. It could be that my answer there doesn't (completely) apply anymore, because browsers and their engines change fast...

***What about the memory***
Not a big problem. Yes, Chrome can be a bit of resource hog at times, but the JS isn't always to blame. Write clean code, and the memory footprint won't be too different on most browsers.
If you create a huge constructor, then V8 will create a larger hidden class, but if that class specifies a lot of properties already, then chances of their being a need for additional hidden classes is smaller.
And of course, each function is an instance of the `Function` class. This being a native (and *very* important) type in a functional language will most likely be a highly optimized class anyway.
Anyway: as far as memory usage is concerned: V8 does a pretty good job managing memory. Far better than IE's of old, for example. So much so that the V8 engine is used for server-side JS (as in node.js), if memory really was an issue, then you wouldn't dream of running V8 on a server that must be up and running as much as possible, now would you?

***Is this just Chrome***
Yes, in a way. V8 does have a special take on how it consumes and runs JS. Rather than JIT-compiling your code to bytecode and running that, it compiles the AST straight into machine code. Again, like the hidden-classes trickery, this is to increase performance.
I know I included this graph in my answer on CR, but just for completeness' sake: Here's a graph that shows the differences between chrome (bottom) and other JS engines (top)
[image: Bytecode vs machine-code]

Notice that below the bytecode instructions and the CPU, there's an (orange) interpreter layer. That's what V8 doesn't need, owing to the JS being translated into machine code directly.
The downside being that this makes certain optimizations harder to do, especially concerning the ones where DOM data and user input is being used in the code (for example: `someObject[document.getElementById('inputField').value]`) and that the initial processing of the code is harder on the CPU.
The upside is: once the code is compiled into machine code, it's the fastest you're going to get, and running the code is likely to cause less overhead. A bytecode interpreter is heavier on the CPU most of the time, that's why busy loops on FF and IE can cause the browser to alert the user of a *"running script"* asking them if they want to stop it.

## [more on V8 internals here](https://developers.google.com/v8/design?hl=en)

Comment: First of all, thanks for the effort you put into this answer... You say the hidden class is related to the constructor function? In my `create()` function I instantiate a brand-new `Created` function with each call. So each time I call `create()`, another hidden class is created and retained? If not, then could you elaborate on the mechanism by which all these disparate instances of `Created` are correlated and made to safely share the same hidden class?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: V8 won't create new hidden classes for each call. Of that, I'm quite sure. Rather it'll make a hidden class for the `Created` function, and define at least 1 property: `prototype` which, after each call will be assigned a different reference for the particular instance your `create` function returns. `Created` will reference a hidden class, but for each function call, `Created` will point to an instance of the same hidden class, thus not consuming an insane amount of memory. I'll update my answer with some more details once I stop shaking (fever is a bitch :-P)

Comment: That makes sense... now take some aspirins and a nap :) I'll chew on it for a while in the meantime.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Added another blob of what resembles an answer. I will be needing my nap now, but as I was writing this, an awful lot started to come back to me. My latest edit is what I think you really wanted to know, my initial answer was a bit all over the place. I'll probably re-read and heavily re-edit my answer once I'm feeling better, though :). Meanwhile: +1 for an extremely interesting question... Not enough questions concerning the nitty-gritty on SO if you ask me

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik also read this excellent blog post: http://www.jayconrod.com/posts/52/a-tour-of-v8-object-representation

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That is indeed a great read, also including a clear-cut answer to my actual question: "Maps contain other information as well, like the size of the object and pointers to constructors and prototypes". So the constructor *is* retained, after all.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik exactly :) the source code is also very accessible.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Although I've found out some time ago that the constructor is in fact retained (knowledge gained from inspecting the source code), it is far from trivial to deduce *why* it is retained. That takes an actual human explaining it to you :)

Comment: I have awarded the bounty to this answer to reward the effort, even though I am a) generally not satisfied with it and b) don't think it explains why the constructor is retained. This is why I have not accepted it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I completely agree with you on that... I was actually hoping for people to point out a couple of things in the comments, so I could complete this answer. From what I gather, the main reason for that retention is that these hidden classes are used for properties. If an instance of `Function` and an object literal both have a property `x`, then they'll both point to the same hidden class, but delete that property and then, based on their initial hidden class, they can both be set to reference another hidden class. If you didn't retain that info, that would become a tad harder

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: It's been over a year, but I recently revisited this question, and started thinking about what might be happening inside the V8 engine, and why. I think that, this time around, I do have an explanation as to why the name `Created` is retained, so I updated my answer

Answer (score 4):

I don't know much about Chrome's internals, so this is just a guess, but it seems to me that Chrome is performing some kind of static analysis on the code which created the function, and storing that for debugging purposes.

Take a look at this example:

```
> function create(proto) {
    object = {}
    object.x = {}
    x = object.x
    x.func = function() {}
    x.func.prototype = proto
    return new object.x.func
}
undefined
> create()
x.func {}
```

`x.func`? There's no way JavaScript has any built-in way for you to access the name of the variable a function was initially assigned to. Chrome *must* be doing that for its own reasons.

Now look at this example:

```
> function newFunc() {
  return function() {}
}

> function create(proto) {
    object = {}
    object.x = {}
    x = object.x
    x.func = newFunc()
    x.func.prototype = proto
    return new object.x.func
}
undefined
> create()
Object {}
```

In this example, since we created the function in a separate closure before assigning it to a variable, Chrome doesn't know the "name" of the function, so it just says "Object".

---

These examples lead me to guess the following answers to your questions:

> What exactly does Chrome's JavaScript engine retain to make that object presentation in the console work? Is it the constructor function, or just the function name?

It performs a static analysis of the code, and stores a string containing the function's "name" somewhere.

> Is that retention needed for anything more substantial than console printout?

Probably not.

> What is the effect of such retention on memory consumption? What if, for example, the constructor function (or even its name) is abnormally huge?

I'm not sure, but I'm guessing it's very unlikely to be an issue. Since the name of the function is determined using static analysis, the potential size of the function name is limited by the size of variable names in the script which created it (unless perhaps you're using `eval`, in which case I'm not sure).

> Is it just Chrome? I've retested with Firebug and Safari, their consoles don't present the object that way. But do they still retain the same data, for other possible purposes (e.g. due to a genuine concern inherent to a JavaScript VM)?

I doubt it, this seems to be something specific to Chrome used to make debugging a bit easier. As far as I can tell, there's no other reason for a feature like this to exist.

Comment: This is again just about function naming. Chrome has some extra smartness by which it *names an anonymous function*. This concern is completely orthogonal to the function's role as a constructor because it happens *at function creation time*, not at its *invocation time*, whether in the role of a constructor or otherwise.

Comment: Whereas the point of my question is, *how can Chrome navigate from the object to the object's constructor*? It may possibly be navigating just to the constructor's *name*: we don't have a proof either way.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik You are correct. Chrome is either storing a reference to the object's constructor, or a reference to its "name" in some hidden property on the object. As I said though, I don't know much about Chrome's internals so I can't say for sure one way or the other.

Comment: I guess only a guy intimate with Chrome's (or Chromium's) internals could provide an insightful answer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Correct. Perhaps you could ask about this on the [Chromium mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-discuss). I obviously can't guarantee you'll get an answer, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try that in a couple of days if nothing satisfactory comes along here; don't want to be labelled a cross-poster :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: Check the link in my answer, and the graphs, and the gibberish (perhaps). Chrome creates _classes_ for each instance, this includes functions (And thus constructors). That's the gist of it, and the reason behind chrome's behaviour being different every now and then (all within the bounds of the ECMAScript specs, though)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am not a Google Chrome expert, however I think that these are not browser-specific, and can be explained by basic Javascript rules.

> What exactly does Chrome's JavaScript engine retain to make that
>   object presentation in the console work? Is it the constructor
>   function, or just the function name?

Each Object or Function in Javascript has its inheritance chain, going up, all the way to the basic prototype.

You can not circumvent this by setting the prototype property to undefined, although it may seem like it from the console output.

So it is the whole constructor function that is retained because of inheritance, although not available to be accessed through global scope.

> Is that retention needed for anything more substantial than console
>   printout?

Yes, it is needed for the prototype inheritance system to work.

> What is the effect of such retention on memory consumption? What if,
>   for example, the constructor function (or even its name) is abnormally
>   huge?

Yes, this can cause a memory leak if used improperly.

This is why you should always delete and clean unused variables, so these and their prototypes can get collected by the garbage collector.

> Is it just Chrome? I've retested with Firebug and Safari, their
>   consoles don't present the object that way. But do they still retain
>   the same data, for other possible purposes (e.g. due to a genuine
>   concern inherent to a JavaScript VM)?

This should work the same way across all browsers, because prototypal inheritance works the same. I have however not specifically tested for it. Please note that the console outputs int browsers can differ, and this does not mean anything, as each browser can implement its console in its own way.

Comment: Have you taken into account the fact that the prototype chain does not involve constructor functions? A prototype *may* have a reference to its respective constructor, via `constructor` property, but that has to be explicitly set, which I demonstrably didn't.

Comment: Yes, it does. By using the 'new' keyword, you invoked the creation of a new object 'cc' using the constructor 'Created'. The 'cc' variable inherited the prototype 'undefined' from 'Created' so nothing was added to the 'cc' object, but anyway, 'cc' is a descendant of 'Created'. A Constructor function or an Object can be a prototype.

Comment: By `'cc' is a descendant of 'Created'` do you mean `create().__proto__ === Created`? If not, could you clarify *how to navigate from `cc` to `Created`*?

Comment: I mean the prototypal inheritance chain goes like this:
cc -> Created -> Object

Comment: OK, so your claim is that `create().__proto__ === Created`. This is trivial to refute using my second version of `create()`: `cc = create(); cc.__proto__ === GlobalCreated` evaluates to `false`.

Comment: No, 'create()' isn't involved in any of this. It is only a wrapper function, that is irrelevant to any of this discussion.
The 'Created()' is the constructor function.

Comment: `create()` is a *function call*, not a function, and it evaluates to a new object as returned from `new Created()`.

Comment: Yes of course. Consider this: should you omit the wrapper function, the only change would be the accessibility of the 'Created' function from the global scope, which would not change anything related to the inheritance. The inheritance is done by invoking the 'new' operator, and that only takes the 'Created' as an argument, it doesn't know, or care, about the scope in which it is called.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46747/discussion-between-maksion-and-marko-topolnik)

Answer (score 0):

```
//The real method to do clone
function doClone(source, keys, values, result) {
    if (source == null || typeof (source) !== "object") {
        return source;
    }
    if (source.Clone instanceof Function) {
        return source.Clone();
    }
    if (source instanceof Date) {
        if (!(result instanceof Date)) {
            result = new Date();
        }
        result.setTime(source.getTime());
        return result;
    }
    else if (source instanceof Array) {
        if (!(result instanceof Array)) {
            result = [];
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
            result[i] = clone(source[i], keys, values, result[i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
    try {
        if (typeof result !== "object" || result == null) {
            result = new source.constructor();
        } else {
            result.constructor = source.constructor;
        }
        if (source.prototype) {
            result.prototype = source.prototype;
        }
        if (source.__proto__) {
            result.__proto__ = source.__proto__;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        if (Object.create) {
            result = Object.create(source.constructor.prototype);
        } else {
            result = {};
        }
    }
    if (result != null) {
        // ReSharper disable once MissingHasOwnPropertyInForeach
        for (var property in source) {
            if (source.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                try {
                    var descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, property);
                    if (descriptor != null) {
                        if (descriptor.get || descriptor.set) {
                            Object.defineProperty(result, property, descriptor);
                        } else {
                            descriptor.value = clone(descriptor.value, keys, values, result[property]);
                            Object.defineProperty(result, property, descriptor);
                        }
                    } else {
                        result[property] = clone(source[property], keys, values, result[property]);
                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    result[property] = clone(source[property], keys, values, result[property]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

//The portal of clone method
function clone(source, keys, values, result) {
    var index = keys.indexOf(source);
    if (index !== -1) {
        return values[index];
    }
    result = doClone(source, keys, values, result);
    index = keys.indexOf(source);
    if (index !== -1) {
        values[index] = result;
    } else {
        keys.push(source);
        values.push(result);
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * Core functions
 */
var X = {
    /**
     * Clone indicated source instance
     * @param {} source The source instance to be clone
     * @param {} target If indicated, copy source instance to target instance.
     * @returns {} 
     */
    Clone: function (source, target) {
        return clone(source, [], [], target);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -6):

You return a new instance from create to a object called Created.

```
create()()
> TypeError: object is not a function
```

If you were to remove the 'new' keyword, then you would expose the Created function to the caller's scope.