# jQuery + access to the name of the function

Tags: jquery, function

I now is a silly question but is this, I can give the name of the current function? I am really interested in this because I usually use the console and i want to get it

```
var debug = true;
var myFunction = $( "div" ).on( "click", function(e) {
    //
    var error = "";
    var something = true;
    //
    if(something == true) error = "Something has happened"; 
    if(debug)
        console.log("Ups!" + myFunction.name + " >> "+ error);
    //
});
```

Thanks in advance

This doesn't work in my jQuery example

[Can I get the name of the currently running function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a named function instead of anonymous, i.e. give it a name:

```
$( "div" ).on( "click", function myFunction(e) {
    console.log("Ups!" + myFunction.name);
});
```

Also, you need to understand that with the code

```
var something = $("div").on("click", function() {})
```

`something` will be an instance of jQuery, not a callback function of course. So once again: use named function.

Answer (score 0):

```
arguments.callee.toString();
```

will get you the entire callee line of code (i.e. *function MyFunction()*) then just substring it out from there.

**Update**
  for your exact situation, try

```
(function() {console.log("Ups!" + arguments.callee.toString() + " error");})();
```

sometimes declaring the action as an inline function makes things tick a little better.

Comment: This doesn't work in my jQuery example, but in js function is perfect

Comment: @lmcDevloper try the last line in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the function name using `arguments.callee` or `arguments.callee.name`.

- `arguments.callee` returns the name with a brackets (`myFunction()`).
- `arguments.callee.name` returns the name without those brackets (`myFunction`).

Comment: This doesn't work in my jQuery example, but in js function is perfect