# How can I tell what function I'm in?

Tags: javascript

I'm using a log function to debug in the console.  I want to know what function I'm logging from in the browser console.  I don't want to use the debugger.

```
function doSomething() {}

console.log(doSomething.name);
```

Basically I want the `name` property from `Function.name` with out knowing what `doSomething` is.  Is this possible?

Is there some component of JS that tracks what function I'm in and that I have access to.?

Comment: It seems like you're looking to print the stack. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/591857/how-can-i-get-a-javascript-stack-trace-when-i-throw-an-exception) may help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get the name of the currently running function in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

Comment: You could also modify the stacktrace to help you out : http://stackoverflow.com/a/635852/1606432

Comment: I would have thought there would be something on `this` and not `arguments`, but I don't see anything that references that.