# Get current function name in strict mode

Tags: javascript, strict

I need the current function name as a string to log to our log facility. But `arguments.callee.name` only works in loose mode. How to get the function name under `"use strict"`?

Comment: If you are able to modify the function's body to add logging code, can't you just hard-code the function name? What advantage would you have if you could read it from a property?

Comment: @nnnnnn someone keeps renaming functions but forgets to update the log line.

Comment: did you find a nice solution for it?
creating an Error object may have a performance impact, so, I'm keep looking the nice way to get the function name.

Comment: @Kostanos not directly, but a workaround for that particular case what was to type `log('^FUNAME^')` instead and then use my own tiny parser on production that would replace ^FUNAME^ with a current function name which is found after the preceeding word `function`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

For logging/debugging purposes, you can create a new `Error` object in the logger and inspect its `.stack` property, e.g.

```js
function logIt(message) {
    var stack = new Error().stack,
        caller = stack.split('\n')[2].trim();
    console.log(caller + ":" + message);
}

function a(b) {
    b()
}

a(function xyz() {
    logIt('hello');
});
```

Comment: Your answer is a little bit complicated, but it shows the idea.

Comment: A great answer @georg. Note that  ``[2]`` is relative to this example only, if  you have for example  a stack  containing three parent functions in this case we must change **2**  to **3**

Comment: @hamism: `stack[2]` is always the function that called the logger, no matter how deep the stack is.

Comment: Now this is a really nice idea :)

Comment: It is a clever solution for logging/debugging. To anyone else considering using this in production code though (in my case, for event tracking), be warned: *"This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future."* (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack)

Answer (score 6):

You can bind function as its context then you can access its name via `this.name`property:

```
function x(){
  console.log(this.name);
}
x.bind(x)();
```

Comment: This is clever.

Comment: This is clever, but the effect of bind is permanent, and the value of this cannot be changed again, which can cause bugs. Perharps, x.call(x) might be a better solution

Comment: @Eazicoding binding does not affect the original function reference. `bind()` creates a copy of the function with the new context.

Answer (score 3):

After little research here is a good solution :

```
function getFnName(fn) {
  var f = typeof fn == 'function';
  var s = f && ((fn.name && ['', fn.name]) || fn.toString().match(/function ([^\(]+)/));
  return (!f && 'not a function') || (s && s[1] || 'anonymous');
}



function test(){
    console.log(getFnName(this));
}

test  = test.bind(test);

test(); // 'test'
```

Source : https://gist.github.com/dfkaye/6384439

Comment: But that doesn't work from within the function unless you already have a reference to the function. OP asked for a replacement for `arguments.callee.name`...

Answer (score 3):

Building on @georg solution, this one returns just the function name. Note though that it may fail if called from an anonymous function

```js
function getFncName() {
    const stackLine = (new Error())!.stack!.split('\n')[2].trim()
    const fncName = stackLine.match(/at Object.([^ ]+)/)?.[1]
    return fncName
}

function Foo() {
    console.log(getFncName()) // prints 'Foo'
}
```

Comment: This only works in Chromium based browsers

Answer (score 2):

just an update to get the full name :

```
function logIt(message) {
    var stack = new Error().stack,

    //  update is on this line
    caller = stack.split('\n')[2].trim().split(/\s+/)[1];

    console.log(caller.trim().split(/\s+/)[1];);
}

function a(b) {
  b()
}

a(function xyz() {
  logIt('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to dynamically retrieve function names [like magic variables] is the use of scoped variables, and the Function.name property.

```
{
  function foo() {
    alert (a.name);
  }; let a = foo
}
{
  function foo2() {
    alert(a.name)
  }; let a = foo2
};
foo();//logs foo
foo2();//logs foo2
```

Note: Nested functions cease to be source elements, and are hence not hoisted. Also, this technique cannot work with anonymous functions.

Comment: Problematic general solution, because usually the code that needs the name is doing something like reporting errors, and lives somewhere else. You don't want to have to go change all the original code for the library code.

Comment: Yes I agree you are right. This was answer was while ago when I was still ignorant. I soon after created a module to help read functions including the function name.

Answer (score -1):

If (like me) you want to define this elsewhere and call it generically, you can store the code as a string somewhere global or import it, then `eval()` it wherever to access the current function name. (Using eval keeps the context at the point of invocation.)

There's gotta be a way to do this without using a string, but whatever.

```
SomeObject.whatFunc =
  'const s = new Error().stack;' +
  "const stackLine = new Error().stack.split('\\n')[2].trim();" +
  'const fncName = stackLine.match(/(?<=at )(.*)(?= \\()/gm)[0];' +
  'console.log(fncName);'

// Whereever you want the func name
function countBananas('weeee') {
  eval(SomeObject.whatFunc)
  // blah blah blah
}

countBananas() // logs 'countBananas'
```