# Currently running javascript function name?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This works fine AFAIK:

```
(function f() {
    console.log(f.name);  //logs f
})();
```

But some of the answers [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript) are a lot longer, which makes me think that I might be missing a gotcha (In other words it works in this case, BUT ...) with the above statement?

Here's a slightly different typescript variation:

```
function f1() {} 
function f2(f:Function) {
   console.log(f.name);
}

f2(f1);
```

Comment: In your code you already know `f`'s name

Comment: True, but I think it should work if that were a function argument to another function as well right?

Comment: Please come up with a valid use case.

Comment: This surely is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1013279/295783

Comment: The use case is when the function is the name of a Validator - See how validator decorators are defined in class validator (The typescript library).  I wish to use the decorator's name directly instead of a static field name defined on a different class.

Comment: Did none of the 17 answers on that question work for your case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get the name of the currently running function in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013239/can-i-get-the-name-of-the-currently-running-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

The `Function.name` property is only available in ES6/ES2015-compliant engines.  So for example if you try to access it without additional configuration in Typescript you will get the error:

> [ts] Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Function'.

So for typescript include `es2015` in your --lib value to get the property declaration.

```
    {
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "lib": ["es2015"],                        /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
        ...
    }
```