# How to find the script path from his own js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find the script path of my own js file in itself.

So I want have as a string "C:\files\MyProject\MyScripts\MyJavaScript.js".

How is that possible?

Comment: It's totally unclear...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get script path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161159/get-script-path)

Comment: Why you need script path? If you just want to know where the js file to understand the implementation, you can search this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is how I made it:

```
function ScriptPath() {
  var scriptPath = '';
  try {
    //Throw an error to generate a stack trace
    throw new Error();
  }
  catch(e) {
    //Split the stack trace into each line
    var stackLines = e.stack.split('\n');
    var callerIndex = 0;
    //Now walk though each line until we find a path reference
    for(var i in stackLines){
      if(!stackLines[i].match(/http[s]?:\/\//)) continue;
      //We skipped all the lines with out an http so we now have a script reference
      //This one is the class constructor, the next is the getScriptPath() call
      //The one after that is the user code requesting the path info (so offset by 2)
      callerIndex = Number(i) + 2;
      break;
    }
    //Now parse the string for each section we want to return
    pathParts = stackLines[callerIndex].match(/((http[s]?:\/\/.+\/)([^\/]+\.js)):/);
  }

  this.fullPath = function() {
    return pathParts[1];
  };

  this.path = function() {
    return pathParts[2];
  };

  this.file = function() {
    return pathParts[3];
  };

  this.fileNoExt = function() {
    var parts = this.file().split('.');
    parts.length = parts.length != 1 ? parts.length - 1 : 1;
    return parts.join('.');
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try (Jquery):

```
var myScriptDetails = $('script');
```

myScriptDetails will contain details regarding the script, including its location.

Comment: myScriptDetails will contain details of all the script linked on the page. The question here is what will the script file do to find it's own location.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution. I think this is exactly what u want :)

Put this code in each of your linked script file

```
var scriptEls = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' );
var thisScriptEl = scriptEls[scriptEls.length - 1];
var scriptPath = thisScriptEl.src;
var scriptFolder = scriptPath.substr(0, scriptPath.lastIndexOf( '/' )+1 );

console.log(scriptPath +"  "+ scriptFolder );// you can save these in any variable also
```

I tested it with this HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head> 
      <title>testing...</title>  
      <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/test2.js"></script> 
      <script type="text/javascript" src="../test3.js"></script> 
    </head>  
    <body>
     content area
    </body>
</html>
```

And found this Output in console:

```
file:///D:/workspace/dbshell/www/test.js  file:///D:/workspace/dbshell/www/          test.js:6
file:///D:/workspace/dbshell/www/js/test2.js  file:///D:/workspace/dbshell/www/js/   test2.js:6
file:///D:/workspace/dbshell/test3.js  file:///D:/workspace/dbshell/                 test3.js:6
```

Special thanks to [meouw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12161/meouw)..
Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Client-side you can't access the physical path. You can get the `src` attribute of the `script` tag though.

Server-side you can get the physical path. For example (C#):

```
Path.GetFullPath(path)
```

Answer (score 0):

For finding full path of URL in JavaScript use this location.href

Answer (score 0):

If you can define absolute path of server as constant variable,

you can do it by casting from `window.location.href`. remove host prefix `window.location.host` from `window.location.href` and prepand with server's absolute path.

Try:

```
 console.log(window.location.href);
```