# How to get the location (src) of a javascript file?

Tags: javascript

How can a javascript file know where it is located? For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mysite.com/scripts/howdy.js"></script>
```

How can the code in `howdy.js` know about `http://mysite.com/scripts/howdy.js`?

Edit: Clarification. I cannot rely on searching the DOM for my script tag because I need to know about it before the DOM may be ready.

Comment: I'm curious, why do you need this info?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How might I get the script filename from within that script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710957/how-might-i-get-the-script-filename-from-within-that-script)

Comment: @tenfour - There are other scripts that howdy.js may pull in from the same directory and I can't be certain where howdy.js will be hosted (test, prod, qa, client host, etc). It's not awesome but it is a business requirement.

@Marcel - Yes, you are right, It is a dup. But I'll leave it up as I couldn't find that answer with the search terms I used.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the moment in which the current script is being executed, will be the last `script` element in the DOM, therefore you can get it by:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
    currentScriptSrc = scripts[scripts.length-1].src;
```

Check this [example](http://jsbin.com/umuyo3/edit) that loads this [script](http://jsbin.com/iyure3).

**Edit:** Taking in consideration the @kangax's comment, about the `async` and `defer` attributes, the only safe way IMO, previously knowing the file name, would be to inspect the `script` elements on the page, examining its `src` attribute, some libraries like [Scriptaculous.us](http://github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/blob/master/src/scriptaculous.js#L54-62) use this technique, for example:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
    len = scripts.length,
    re = /howdy\.js$/,
    src, howdyScriptSrc;

while (len--) {
  src = scripts[len].src;
  if (src && src.match(re)) {
    howdyScriptSrc = src;
    break;
  }
}
​
```

Comment: Cool, didn't know you were guaranteed this information. But it seems consistent on every browser I've tried. Thanks!

Comment: Consider Kangax's comment which led me here: http://twitter.com/kangax/status/22208127507

Comment: @zachleat: Thanks!, Yes, I completely forgot the defer and async attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Give this script tag an id, and write:

```
var src = document.getElementById('scriptID').attributes['src'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function getScriptSourceName(name){
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for (i=0;i<scripts.length;i++){
        if (scripts[i].src.indexOf(name) > -1)
            return scripts[i].src;
    }
}

getScriptSourceName('howdy.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1]; // add .src to get href
//or
document.getElementsByTagName("script")[document.getElementsByTagName("script").length-1];
//for (maybe) better compatibility
```

Which gets the last script in the DOM. If your script is being executed while it is being loaded, this will return the right element.

Save it to a variable for use in functions which will be used later.

```
var thisScript = document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1];
```