# Data attributes and script tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a project I'm working on called Natalie.

What it does, (twitter.com is a good example if you don't understand my explanation) is it uses the hash tag, to load a page via XHR, and then inserts it into the page, so you can have a generic look that doesn't change between pages, that doesn't need PHP or the like.

It has several configuration properties, the main ones being:

- A selector to use to find the place you would like to insert the loaded page.
- A folder path to use at the document root. (Think Apache configuration)
- The page to load if there isn't a hash tag.

I currently have them in an object called `Natalie.config` but I would like to do something like `<script src="Natalie.js" data-natalie-docroot="/Folder"></script>`

Is there any way to tell which tag the script is running from, or do you have to search all script tags for these attributes?

I would much rather prevent something like this from happening if possible:

```
<script src="Natalie.js"></script>
<script data-natalie-docroot="/Folder"></script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Javascript any way to know what host script was loaded from?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578923/in-javascript-any-way-to-know-what-host-script-was-loaded-from)

Comment: @Anurag, it's not the same. This question is asking for the script **element** that a script was loaded from.

Comment: @Anurag No. That's trying to determine where the script was loaded from. I'm after finding the script tag itself.

Comment: @Box9, @tylermwashburn - the question doesn't seem similar based on the title, but they are. It answers exactly what you need - the `<script>` element which is being currently executed. Whether its the `src` attribute or the `data-natalie-docroot` attribute you need once the script element has been determined is not relevant - the root problem is the same.

Comment: @Anurag Duplicate problem. That's incredibly common on this site. The QUESTION is what needs to be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd simply put `data-natalie-docroot="/Folder"` on the `<body>` tag. The reason being that it is not *directly* associated to the script itself. Your approach also wouldn't work if someone wanted to load your script using a dynamic script loader.