# Get element by src attribute with javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript

How to get the element by its `src` attribute?
I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mysrc.js?id=1000">
```

I would need to get that element on a variable. All I know is `getAttribute("src")` returns the src. If I knew anything else besides the actual src which is all I have. I can't use jQuery, just plain JS.

Comment: document.querySelector("script[src*='1000']")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9496574/886539

Comment: just love the clowns who downvote this kind of questions

Comment: You need to write your own method, see this a good reference [How to get the location (src) of a javascript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3548857/how-to-get-the-location-src-of-a-javascript-file)

Comment: @dandavis asnwer works, but keep in mind it won't get script elemenements *below* executing code. Here http://jsfiddle.net/J6ZDf/ looking for `"script[src*='1000']` works, but looking for `"script[src*='2000']` doesn't. I think it would apply to any method. so you will have to place the code as the last code on the page.

Comment: it can be executed onload, in a timeout, or in conjunction with a domReady function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get query string value from script path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716612/how-do-i-get-query-string-value-from-script-path)

Answer (score 4):

You can do like this

```
<script id="mysrc" type="text/javascript" src="mysrc.js?id=1000">

var src = document.getElementById("mysrc").getAttribute("src")
console.log(src.split('id=')[1]); //1000
```