# How can I manage GET parameter calling a script with src?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, get, widget

I see many widgets that allow this :

```
<script src="http://www.mywebsite.it/widget/widget.js?year=2000" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How can I manage that year? I mean, `widget.js`, on loading, does an ajax call to an `aspx` page. And I'd like to pass that `year` to the `aspx` page.

How can I do it from the .js?

Comment: what's the problem here? Why can't you make a simple, plain, vanilla GET request to http://www.mywebsite.it/widget/widget.js?year=2000 ?

Comment: Check this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716612/how-do-i-get-query-string-value-from-script-path

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/979975/how-to-get-the-value-from-url-parameter

Comment: year is dinamic! If I call the widget with year=2000 or year=2001 it make different results. So, on widget.js, I must do 2 different ajax call to the aspx.

Comment: Claudio Redi's link is a good one.  If you can add an `id` attribute to the tag, you can make things slightly simpler (and more robust, on the chance that not all browsers order scripts the obvious way).

Comment: ok. so? where's the problem? do to ajax requests? Where's the problem?

Comment: @ParthThakkar: Your suggestion does not exactly deal with the question (read more closely) and assumes that the parameter can be known and hardcoded elsewhere.

Comment: ok wait. either i don't get the question or the question isn't clear. My question: Do you want to make requests to http://www.mywebsite.it/widget/widget.js and pass the parameter `year` to get different variables?

Comment: @goldilocks : what do you mean as "id attribute to the tag"? Can you give to me an example?

Comment: @markzzz: looks like **dda** beat me to it, see his answer

Comment: Ah! Well, I don't like this approxh with "id". As said by Ashley in the other post, "The punchline is that since scripts in HTML (not XHTML) are executed as loaded, this will allow a script to find itself as it is always the last script in the page when it’s triggered". I trust him :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your script an id, say "scr1".

```
<script id="src1" src="http://www.mywebsite.it/widget/widget.js?year=2000" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then you can do:

```
var myScript = document.getElementById('scr1');
var src=myScript.src;
var p=/[?&]year=(\d+)/
var r=p.exec(src);
// r[1] contains the year
```

HTH