# How to determine parameters from <script>?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get query string value from script path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716612/how-do-i-get-query-string-value-from-script-path)

I have:

index.html:

```
...
<script src="myscript.js?param1=1&param2=2">
...
```

myscript.js:

```
function getScriptParam(paramName){
  // How to determine the script parameters value?
  var value = HOW TO DO?;

  return value;
}

var param1 = getScriptParam('param1');  // param1 should be '1'
```

Thanks.

Comment: @trung - note that parameters to JS functions aren't typed-- remove the `String `

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292372/how-to-pass-parameters-to-a-script-tag

Answer (score 0):

You CANNOT pass parameters to myscript.js, SCRIPT tag is used for loading script code only

You CAN pass query string parameter to index.html (e.g. index.html?param1=1&param2=2) and then parse "location.search" property.

Comment: Huh, why? You can pass query in `<script>` and server will see it and is free to process it in whatever manner it wants. The only thing you can't do *directly* is to retrieve this query in JS, but you can still find them in DOM.

Comment: IF script is generated server-side then yes. If script is simple a downloaded JS file - then no. And anyway - the question was about passing parameters from query string to JS function.

Comment: "you can still find them in DOM" and ex.dup. link covers just that.