# How to remove inline styles added by external script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a `<script>` that generates a both `<style>` and inline style attributes with `!important` tags. I'd like to remove all this styling.

My plan was to use a javascript `onload` callback (and some jQuery) to remove the `<style>` block and all inline style attributes — but I can't seem to select any of these elements. Here's what I've been toying with:

```
var script = document.createElement("script");

script.src      = "//script.path.js";
script.onload   = function(){

    $(this).parent().find("style").remove();
    $(this).parent().find("[style]").removeAttr("style");

};

$(target).append(script);
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that the elements generated by the `<script>` just aren't available in the DOM right away. If I use `setInterval` to check if the elements exist first, I can get this to work. I imagine there's a better way to do this though...

Comment: do you want js that just removes the entire `<style>` tag and its contents?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16231055/302246), you must append the `script` tag to the DOM *before* setting `onload`.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
$(target).append(script);

script.src = "//script.path.js";
script.onload = function(){
  $(this).parent().find("style").remove();
  $(this).parent().find("[style]").removeAttr("style");
};
```

https://jsbin.com/minoyeyicu/edit?html,js,output

**UPDATE**: Having clarified that the issue is that the `style` tag/attributes haven't yet been applied to the DOM until *after* the downloaded script has *executed*, one alternative (depending on whether the loaded script is under your control), is to pass a `callback` parameter to the loaded script and have the loaded script execute the callback when it finishes executing (which is how the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Loading_the_Maps_API) works). E.g.

```
script.src = '//script.path.js?callback=removeStyles'
```

In order to use the `callback` parameter from within `script.path.js`, something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716930/302246) could be done.

Comment: this is correct, but your bin doesn't demonstrate the style tags being added into the document via the script.

Comment: Oh, I understand your issue now... Is the loaded script under your control? If so, you could specify a callback to execute at the end of the script (similar to how [Google Maps can use the value  of a `callback` parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)) in the URL to execute the given method once it's ready to load. E.g. `script.src = '//script.path.js?callback=removeStyles'`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4716930/302246) on how to use this parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately, the loaded script is not within my control.