# Pull value from js request querystring

Tags: javascript, typescript

I thought this would be much easier but obviously I missing something.

I have a reference to a javascript file in my html e.g.

`<script src="myfile.js?k=123456"></script>`

With typescript I want to pull the k query string value and use it when processing in my typescript/javascript. How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get query string value from script path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716612/how-do-i-get-query-string-value-from-script-path)

Comment: did you try to put this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript into your myfle.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector()`, or add an `id` to your script tag, and get the query string value from its `src` property:

```js
let value = document.querySelectorAll('script')[1].src.split('k=')[1];
let value2 = document.getElementById('script').src.split('k=')[1];

console.log(value, value2);
```

```html
<script id="script" src="myfile.js?k=123456"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you support modern browsers, then you can use [`URL.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) to parse out the `k` parameter like:

```js
const src = document.body.querySelector('script').src;
const params = (new URL(src)).searchParams;
console.log(params.get('k'))
```

```html
<script src="myfile.js?k=123456"></script>
```