# How to get the currently loading script name and the url variable of the script?

Tags: javascript

I am loading a script using the script embed tag and I want to get the url variables and the loading script name inside the script. Is it possible? For Example,

```
<script src="test.js?id=12"></script>
```

Inside test.js is there any way to get the url variable id?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710957/how-might-i-get-the-script-filename-from-within-that-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all your efforts I have made that working by assigning an id attribute in the script tag and accessed via jQuery,

```
<script src="test.js?id=12" id="myScript"></script>

var currentScript = $("#myScript").attr('src'); //This will give me my script src
```

Thanks,

Karthik

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the answers in the linked post, FWIW with Firefox 4 only you can (with caveats); [`document.currentScript.src`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.currentScript) which will return the full url, including arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a variable from the current URL you can use this:

```
function queryParser(url){
    this.get=function(p){return this.q[p];}
    this.q={};
    this.map=function(url){
        url=url || window.location.search.substring(1);
        var url=url.split('&');
        var part;
        for(var i=0;i<url.length;i++){
            part=url[i].split('=');
            this.q[part[0]]=part[1];
        }
    }
    this.map(url);
}
var query=new queryParser();
// assuming you have ?test=something
alert(query.get('test'));
```

I recommend you map the result, so you don't re-parse whenever you want to find a specific element.

I don't really know why you'd pass a query string in a script tag like that, unless you specifically want off-site includes with a simple robust system for various effects. Or are actually using PHP to handle that request.

If you want to "send" a variable to one of your scripts, you can always do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar="I'm in global scope, all scripts can access me";
</script>
<script src="test.js?id=12"></script>
```

If you really need to get the URL of the currently included script, you can use the code supplied by my peers in the other answers, you can then use:

```
var query=new queryParser(scriptURL);
alert(query.get('id'));// would alert 12 in your case
```

Comment: Nice function, but the OP first needs to get the URL of the currently running script.

Comment: Check the last paragraph of my answer, then check the third paragraph. Then go to the OP and read his second question.

Comment: Yes, I read those, but how do you get `scriptURL` from within the script?

Comment: @Marcel check the answers from @alex and @ivo_es.

Answer (score 0):

Navigating through the link on your comments you can get the proper answer.
Anyway, to make things easier:

```
var allScripts=document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var indexLastScript= allScripts.length -1;
alert (allScripts[indexLastScript].src);
```

This will show up "test.js?id=12" as a regular String so its up to you to split it in order to get de param.

Hope it helps, I've tried it on the run over the Chrome Javascript Console. :D.

Comment: I know about this solution but my problem is I will put this script in host website and based the id it will load some data from my server and not from the host server. Its simply like loading a widget script.So I wont have assurance like in which position the host will embed my script.Any better ideas?Any How thanks for all you guys!

Comment: @Karthik: when your script runs, the last script element will be the script that's currently running (except in some edge case).