# Get domain of Javascript file

Tags: javascript

So I have a site at http://mysite.com/ and I have a Javascript file on a CDN, the Javascript file could be at http://cdn1.mysite.com/ or http://cdn2.mysite.com/, I need to get the value of the hostname the javascript file is on. Is there any way to do this? I cannot modify the embed code of the javascript file to add a custom ID or add an additional variable on mainsite.com.

The reasons why I need this are far too complicated for one post =)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How might I get the script filename from within that script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710957/how-might-i-get-the-script-filename-from-within-that-script)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get all the scripts you are loading in your page and search by name for the right one

Here is your [example](http://jsfiddle.net/daw5g/)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index of the embedded `<script>` inside `document.getElementsByTagName('script')` you may read the src-attribute of the `<script>` and extract the hostname from that src.