# How can I obtain the hostname or address of my .js script from inside the .js script?

Tags: javascript, src, hostname

I have a web site which downloads the same script from any number of different servers:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://server1.example.com/hello.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://server2.example.com/hello.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://server3.example.com/hello.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://server4.example.com/hello.js"></script>
```

Each script has a locally-scoped variable which has to be the hostname of the server that script was downloaded from: so when I download the script from `server1.example.com` that variable's value has to be `server1.example.com`.

Can this be done *with absolutely no server-side programming*? (AJAX requests can be sent, but the solution cannot include any server-side code)

*Please note that I am looking for the host which the script is hosted on, not the host of the current browser page; that means I am not looking for `window.location`.*

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/710957/how-might-i-get-the-script-filename-from-within-that-script. See that question for a good answer.

Comment: @Elliot Nelson; close but no cigar; some of my `<script>` elements are added using DOM,. after the page is loaded. Those solutions rely on being run at loading time and assume the script is the last one in the document.

Answer (score 1):

I think the below code can help:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
for(var a = 0; a < scripts.length; a++){
    if(scripts[a].src.indexOf('<<<--###-->>>') > 0 ) 
        var ThisScriptPath = scripts[a].src.substr( 0, scripts[a].src.lastIndexOf('/'));
}
```

You will need to replace the **<<<--###-->>>** with your script's name, and you will have the path stored in **ThisScriptPath** (remember to use the final slash)

**Tip**: Use an alert to check the results before getting into production

Comment: using lastIndexOf won't give you necessarily the hostname, since the URL might be: http://hostname.com/js/directory/file.js (so the script would give you http://hostname.com/js/directory

Answer (score -3):

You can extract from window.location.host the first part of the domain name with regex.

You can use that in order to extract the first part

```
var host = window.location.host;
host = host.match(/^[\d\w]+/);
```

Comment: Sorry @Merianos Nikos, but this is not what I'm looking for, and even if it were, using `window.location.hostname` would be a better idea than using a RegEx. See [MDN's window.location reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.location#Properties) for the properties of `window.location`.

Comment: this would be the URL of the webpage and not of the script, if script is added from cross domain.