# Using CloudFront and Amazon S3, or another CDN, can I send all similar requests to one static file?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, static

I would like all the following requests to reach the same static file hosted on Amazon S3, for example:

```
http://cloudfront.net/js/12345.js
http://cloudfront.net/js/54232.js
http://cloudfront.net/js/76543.js
```

would all point to a single static file on Amazon S3 such as:

```
/js/real-file.js
```

then the javascript code in this real file would be able to get the numbers from the request using something like the following found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710957/how-might-i-get-the-script-filename-from-within-that-script#answer-710996):

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var scriptName = scripts[scripts.length-1].src;
```

I know this would be possible using a query parameter such as:

```
/js/real-file.js?a=12345
```

but I would like to know if it's possible to achieve without it.

If not on Amazon, then perhaps using a different CDN service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer solved this for me: [answer-35354677](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16267339/s3-static-website-hosting-route-all-paths-to-index-html#answer-35354677)

> The solution is:
>
> 1. Make sure you have the index route configured for your website. Mostly it is index.html
> 2. Remove routing rules from S3 configurations
> 3. Put a Cloudfront in front of your S3 bucket.
> 4. Configure error page rules for your Cloudfront instance. In the error rules specify:
>
>    - Http error code: 404 (and 403 or other errors as per need)
>    - Error Caching Minimum TTL (seconds) : 0
>    - Customize response: Yes
>    - Response Page Path : /index.html
>    - HTTP Response Code: 200