# Override console.log method without losing the original stack - javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my `logger.js`:

```
const _nativeLog = console.log;
console.log = function (...args) {

  // doing something else in log method

  _nativeLog.apply(this, args)
}
```

After this code, all logs in console sims to be triggered by my `logger.js` file. And it's normal because I fire the `_nativeLog` method inside `logger.js`.

Here is the output:

[image]

My question is that is it possible to keep the original filename that calls the overridden `console.log` method and show it as origin in the console.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-console have a look at eslint rules

Comment: Actually, I do this for debugging purposes. @VirojFernando

Comment: are you using node.js or are your javascript files included in a html file ?

Comment: It's for browser env. @gui3

Comment: It's implementation dependent, but probably there's no way to change that, `console.log` uses internal details to show the stack trace, which you can't do much about...

Answer (score -2):

found this [How might I get the script filename from within that script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710957/how-might-i-get-the-script-filename-from-within-that-script/19807441)

it's kind of ugly and I'm really not sure if it will give you what you want, but you could try this :

```js
const _nativeLog = console.log;
console.log = function (...args) {

  // ... doing something else in log method

  let scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script') // get all scripts loaded
  let file= scripts[scripts.length-1].src // get the last loaded script source

  let text = args[0]
  args[0] = file + " \n " + text

  _nativeLog.apply(this, args)
}
```

Comment: REM : this will not work if you call functions from files in events or in the console or asynchronously, but it gives you the right file if console.log is called at the loading of the script