# Google's +1 Button: How do they do it?

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus-one

Exploring Google's +1 Button, I found two things odd about the code they supply:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
  {lang: 'en-GB'}
</script>

<g:plusone size="tall" href="http://www.google.com"></g:plusone>
```

So I have two questions:
**First:**       How is Google able to use the text between the `script` tags?
**Second:**  Is the syntax `<g:plusone ...` HTML valid? What's this called?

Comment: It isn't namespaced XML since `xmlns:g` is never specified.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> How is Google able to use the text between the script tags?

`<script>` elements are perfectly visible in the DOM:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//FIRST SCRIPT BLOCK</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var s= document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    alert(s.textContent); // "//FIRST SCRIPT BLOCK"
</script>
```

Google's sneaky trick is to put content in a `<script>` that has an external `src`. In this case the `src` overrides the content inside the block and executes the external script instead, but the contents of the `<script>` element are still readable through the DOM even though they do nothing.

> Is the syntax `<g:plusone` ... HTML valid? What's this called?

No. If they made their own doctype for HTML+plusone it could be valid *that*, but it doesn't satisfy validity for HTML, and it isn't even namespace-well-formed in an XHTML document, unless you add an extra `xmlns:g` for it too.

Comment: I'm not sure if I would trust `var s= document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];` What if the script we want access to is not the first `script` element?

Comment: Yeah, that's just an example. In fact what they will be doing is reading the *last* script in the ByTagName list, not the first. Because the page is only partially loaded at run-time, the last `<script>` will be the one you're currently executing. (Unless you use `defer` or `async`.)

Answer (score 2):

> Is the syntax `<g:plusone` ... HTML valid?

No

> What's this called?

Invalid psuedo-namespaces

Comment: Is XML character ":" not specified? First off ":" is just an ASCII symbol. I'm not sure how Google is using it? Is this a class variable?

Comment: @Quentin This certainly helps, as I found w3c documentation on [HTML5 Namespaces](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/namespaces.html)

Answer (score 2):

The first trick is interesting. It looks like a creative way to pass "global" arguments from the page markup to external scripts. There are [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/403967/464709) to find the `<script>` element that sources the code that's currently running, and I would not be surprised if the inner text of that `<script>` element was accessible from the DOM even though the browser ignores it.

In your question, this pattern allows each external client-side script to use (at least) its own localization settings, and also allows server-side code to render that parameter as a side effect of rendering the `<script>` element itself. That's impressive.

The second trick, I'm not so sure about. Basically, I think most browsers would consider the namespaced `<g:plusone>` element as *unknown* or even *invalid*, so they *should* render its content, but it won't do anything, of course, since that element is empty to begin with.

However, client-side code might still be able to match the namespaced element using DOM navigation, and replace it with its own generated content.

Comment: Sure it is. But it's a difficult question.