# How can I read a JSON in the script-tag from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a dynamically generated page where I want to use a static JavaScript and pass it a JSON string as a parameter. I have seen this approach used by Google (see [Google's +1 Button: How do they do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713197/googles-1-button-how-do-they-do-it)).

But how should I read the JSON string from the JavaScript?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myscript.js">{"org": 10, "items":["one","two"]}</script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello
  </body>
</html>
```

In this JavaScript I would like to use the JSON argument `{"org": 10, "items":["one","two"]}` from the HTML document. I don't know if it's best to do it with jQuery or without.

```
$(function() {
    // read JSON

    alert("the json is:")
})
```

Answer (score 232, accepted):

I would change the script declaration to this:

```
<script id="data" type="application/json">{"org": 10, "items":["one","two"]}</script>
```

Note type and id fields. After that

```
var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').textContent);
```

will work just fine in all browsers.

The `type="application/json"` is needed to prevent browser from parsing it while loading.

And the reason why we use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` or `innerText` to read the raw Json text is because `innerHTML` tries to parse the contents as HTML which will lead to slower performance and possible parsing bugs and XSS attacks, and `innerText` won't grab the raw text and will instead look for human-visible text, whereas `textContent` grabs the pure text as-is (which is what you want). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent for more details about why `innerHTML` and `innerText` are bad.

Comment: Well, I want the script-tag point to a JavaScript, so it's not only for JSON. The JSON is only an argument to the script.

Comment: According to HTML5 spec: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/script.html
the `<script>` element that has defined SRC shall not contain anything other than new lines and/or comments. See
"A script element with a src attribute must contain only:" in the link above. Otherwise HTML validator's will complain.

Comment: @WoIIe Because jQuery is used already by TS, check `<script src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>` there.

Comment: I like the jquery usage.  I mean, how many more fractions of a millisecond will you shave off by using vanilla javascript (in this case)?

Comment: Pay attention that this is not safe, it allows XSS,
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xevgEM

Comment: @felixmosh That's true for any inclusion on the page. Same thing can be done with `<style>` for example. So JSON needs to be shielded properly: `</script>` -> `<\/script>` in strings and the like.

Comment: This seems to have some caveats. We had json containing SVGs as strings and they caused json parsing errors when using this technique.  The workaround was to base64 encode it and decode it using atob() before passing to JSON.parse().

Comment: Note: You can't load local JSON files using the `src` attribute this way. `textContent` etc. will return an empty string.

Answer (score 13):

I ended up with this JavaScript code to be independent of jQuery.

```
var jsonElement = document.getElementById('json-script-tag');
var myObject = JSON.parse(jsonElement.textContent);
```

Comment: Why not just give the script an ID and grab it with `document.getElementById`? That way, you don't have to remember to keep it last. Nor will whoever else changes the page in the future.

Comment: The original version of this answer was inspired by the link in the question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713197/googles-1-button-how-do-they-do-it

Comment: Should one really depend on jQuery just to do this?

Comment: @ozanmuyes No, and that’s why I wrote code independent of jQuery.

Answer (score 5):

To read JSON in `<script id="myJSON">` use

```
var manifest= document.getElementById('myJSON').innerHTML; //sets manifest to the text in #myJSON
manifest= JSON.parse(manifest) //Converts text into JSON
```

You can also use methods to point to the script like `document.scripts[0]`

```js
    //var manifest= JSON.parse(document.getElementById('myJSON').innerHTML); /*Shortend of 2&3*/
var manifest= document.getElementById('myJSON').innerHTML; //Gets text in #myJSON
manifest= JSON.parse(manifest) //Converts it into JSON
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML= manifest.name+ '<br/>'+ manifest.otherOptions; //Displays it
console.log('manifest')
console.log(manifest);
```

```html
<head>
<script type="application/json" id="myJSON">
  {"name":"Web Starter Kit", "otherOptions":"directly here"}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="test"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: The `<script id="myJSON">` tag also needs the `type="application/json"` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

```
JSON.parse($('script[src="mysript.js"]').html());
```

or invent some other method to identify the script.

Maybe instead of `.html()` you might need `.text()`. Not sure. Try them both.

Comment: Thanks, it worked when I changed the json to `{"org": 10, "items":["one","two"]}`

Comment: This method is wrong. If a `<script>` tag has the `src` then it MUST NOT have any content at all.

Answer (score 1):

Like that will be working?

```
<script id="data" type="application/json" src="https://mycstripc.co">
var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('data').textContent);
</script>
```