# Php output breaks the Javascript

Tags: php, javascript

i have php variables that is like this

```
var externalData = '<?php echo $matches[0]; ?>';
```

I when i load the source code of the page comes like this

```
var externalData = 'data,data,data,data,data
';
```

this breaks the javascript code, and browser cant run it.

I want to be like this:

```
var externalData = 'data,data,data,data,data';
```

the php output is a full line of a file, so may contains the end of the line.
I test it by hand and working, how i can fix this?

Comment: What is that closing parenthesis doing there?

Comment: sorry just error typing, i remove the parenthesis.

Comment: You should escape the result of $matches[0].  Also the ')' is not valid javascript so it is normal that it will break.

Comment: This is a bad practice. Serialize your PHP data to JSON via `json_encode()`, then parse it client side via `JSON.parse`, possibly from a `<script type="application/json" id="yourAwesomeId"></script>` tag [[see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7956249/1073758)].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) (or `rtrim`) to remove the line break at the end of the string:

```
var externalData = "<?php echo trim($matches[0]); ?>";
```

Alternatively you could pass the whole string to [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php):

```
var externalData = <?php echo json_encode($matches[0]); ?>;
```

This would not *remove* the line break, but it would encode it and the resulting value will be a valid JS string literal (i.e. all other characters that could break the code, such as `'` or `"`, will escaped as well).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should strip all HTML

```
var externalData = "<?php echo strip_tags($matches[0];) ?>");
```

Comment: Line endings to not get stripped, which is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `substr()` to get rid of the last char of string.

Like this:

```
var externalData = "<?php echo substr($matches[0], 0, strlen($matches[0]) - 1); ?>";
```

Comment: Won't work if the break is actually `\r\n` (windows). Also `substr($blah,0,-1)` is more elegant.

Comment: @Dave Thank you! If it runs on windows. `substr($blah,0,-2)` may be OK

Comment: it's not about what it runs on, but where the newline is coming from in the first place. If it's known for sure, then yes this would be fine. If it's uncertain, `rtrim` is probably the better option.