# Should I use <script> tag to pass data from PHP to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, script-tag

The accepted answer to ["How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548) lists a number of methods. One that isn't explicitly mentioned (although it fits under method 2) is discussed in ["How can I read a JSON in the script-tag from JavaScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581133). It works by using the PHP function (copied from [Mathias Bynens](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/json-dom-csp#script))

```
json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES)
```

to write the content of a tag such as

```
<script id="data" type="application/json">{org: 10, items:["one","two"]}</script>
```

(copied from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7956249/4166379) of [c-smile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421163/c-smile)), which is then read from the DOM by JavaScript.

This seems to be the best method for my case (I would rather not do a separate AJAX call), but I'm slightly concerned that it doesn't seem to be standard way of doing these things. Are there potential security issues I should be aware of?

And is this likely to be reasonably future-proof? Is it possible that there will be changes to the `<script>` tag or the way that browsers handle `type="application/json"` that will break this approach?

---

**Update**

Here's an example of the approach:

```
<html>
<head>
<script id="data" type="application/json">
<?php 
$data = array(
    "org" => 10,
    "items" => array("one", "two"),
    "backslash" => "\\",
    "slash" => "/",
    "single quote" => "'",
    "double quote" => "\"",
    "close tag" => "</script>"
);
echo json_encode($data, JSON_HEX_TAG);
?>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var data = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("data").innerHTML);

for(var key in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var p = document.createElement("pre");
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(p);
        p.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data[key].toString()));
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The only thing that you need to be careful with is the string `"</script>"` inside your data, other than that it seems like a pretty good solution.

Comment: Does this work, yes. I've done approaches like this many times over. You will not encounter a functionality issue using this method. Just an organization issue. It is not the recommended standard for developing maintainable code. Ajax would really be your best option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables:

in you php:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    "org" => 10,
    "items" => array("one", "two"),
    "backslash" => "\\",
    "slash" => "/",
    "single quote" => "'",
    "double quote" => "\"",
    "close tag" => "</script>"
);
?>
```

in you html:

```
<script>
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>
</script>
```

And you can call you data with:

```
JSON.parse(data);
```