# Require JS: Detect data-main inside the script

Tags: javascript, requirejs

In require js, is it possible to tell if a script is being loaded as `data-main`? For example, I have a script that can be used both as `data-main` or a module:

```
// script.js
if (this_is_data_main()) {
   console.log('do something main');
} else {
   console.log('do something else');
}
```

I can think of a hack by writing information as global variable, for example:

```
//index.html
<!doctype html>
...
<script> window.app.main = 'script'; </script>
<script data-main="script.js" src="require.js"></script>
```

Updated script.js:

```
// script.js
if (window.app && window.app.main === 'script') {
   console.log('do something main');
} else {
   console.log('do something else');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Summary

RequireJS does not provide an "official" way of doing what you want. There's a unofficial way, which is brittle. However, I don't think you should be relying on detecting whether your script is loaded through `data-main` or not.

#### Long Explanation

RequireJS provides no direct means to do what you are trying to do. If you read the code of RequireJS you'll see that it reads `data-main` and ultimately appends it to the `deps` option of the current configuration. There is no other processing done besides a bit of path computation. (The path computation details are not important to the larger question you're asking here so I'm skipping these details.) By the time RequireJS is done with `data-main`, the code in your question is roughly equivalent to:

```
<script src="require.js"></script>
<script>
  require.config({
    deps: ["script"]
  });
</script>
```

You *could* inspect `deps` and see whether your module is in there. You'd find `deps` at this location `require.s.contexts._.config.deps`. The underscore is the name of the default context, by the way. But as you can probably tell by this bizarre location this is using a private API that could change with future releases of RequireJS. That's one problem. Another problem is that if `require.config` is called another time with a `deps` value, the first value of `deps` will be overwritten. So this would fail depending on circumstances. Too brittle for my taste.

---

Ultimately I would not rely on having module behavior depend on whether the module was loaded by being listed in `data-main` rather than some other way. I've shown above an equivalent to using `data-main`. Here's another one:

```
<script src="require.js"></script>
<script>
  require(["script"]);
</script>
```

And I could list a bunch of other variations. **The point is that from a module loading standpoint `data-main` is a convenience. It should not be given more significance than being a convenience.** I've used `data-main` and the two alternatives shown above in various contexts. The context will usually determine which options are possible or desirable. For instance I've answered questions on SO where the OP was running in a context where RequireJS was already loaded by the time their own code would run. So they just would not have been *even able* to rely on `data-main`. (This can happen, for instance, for components that serve as plug-ins in a larger framework: the framework uses RequireJS so it makes RequireJS available to plugins, but the plugins are limited to adding `script` elements.)

Another issue with relying on `data-main` is that this is a RequireJS thing. It is possible to load AMD modules with other tools like SystemJS or bundle AMD modules using other tools like Webpack. **If your code depends on `data-main` it won't work properly when working with those other tools.**

---

You could have your main module export an initialization function that takes options and configures your module as the user needs it.

If you want something that kicks in immediately upon module loading and not have to call any functions, one way to do it without polluting the global JavaScript space would be to have your module look for a well-known `script` element (which a specific `id` or a specific `class`) that has a type `application/json`. Since it is JSON, it is not executed by the browser but it is accessible to scripts that need it. It would contain a JSON object that your module reads for configuration. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581133/how-can-i-read-a-json-in-the-script-tag-from-javascript) deals with how to get the JSON out of the script.