# Embedding JSON file's content in page

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to embed the content of a JSON file data.json into a Single Page Application (SPA). One way to do this is to embed the content directly as data using a script tag, per this link: [Embeding Arbitrary JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9320427/best-practice-for-embedding-arbitrary-json-in-the-dom).

However, this approach is not perfect in my case, because:

1. data.json is 1000+ lines of code;
2. data.json is used in several places, including the page in
   discussion; and I want to keep just one copy of data.json;

I wonder if it's possible to have a pointer in the page to point to the external JSON file?

Note that this question is different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581133).

Comment: How about some ajax?

Comment: Yeah, Ajax would do. But I still wonder if it's possible to embed it into our page.

Comment: How do you serve the html? PHP? Node.js? or just static html pages?

Comment: It's a Single Page Application (SPA) served by Apache/PHP.

Answer (score 2):

For php you can just use something like this

```
<script>
var data = <?php echo file_get_contents('PATH_TO_JSON_FILE'); ?>;
</script>
```