# var in JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I am referring code one of my colleague and he used Var in JSON file is there any specific reason behind it or he wants to use JS file.

He also mentioned `<script type="text/javascript" src="player-settings.json"></script>`

**JSON:**

```
var globalSettings ={  
         //data
};
var languageToSelect ={  
   "en":"English"
}; 
var menuSettings ={  
   "name":"Menu",
   "isStrictlyLinear":false,
   "pageCompleteOnView":true,
   "completeAllInteraction":false,
   "modules":{  
            //data
   },
   "lessons":{  
            //data
   },
   "topics":{  
            //data
   },
   "pageCompletion":{  
            //data
   },
   "bodySettings":{  
      //data
   }
};
```

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581133/how-can-i-read-a-json-in-the-script-tag-from-javascript) link to know why we used a script tag to load JSON but in my case, he used type as "text/javascript" and in JSON var is used which leads me to confusion. Is there any specific reason to use Var in JSON file?

Comment: That isn't [JSON](http://json.org). Not at all. It's JavaScript code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't JSON. It's JavaScript code. Please check this URL : http://json.org/

Answer (score 2):

The extension used is just wrong, its a javascript file not a json file

Answer (score 1):

data you shared doesn't look like a json.