# Is there any useful mime for <script type="mime" src="..."> except for JS?

Tags: javascript, mime-types, script-tag, dynamic-script-loading

From much reading I conclude:

*The `<script>` tag can store data, but it is only accessible if `src` is not used.*

I want to use `src` because it is how my script-loader works.
Is the type attribute and every mime-types then useless or what?...

I have found that the "text/javascript" (same as "application/javascript") can not be accessed by `.innerText` or `.innerHTML` or `.toString` (hopefully I missed something here).
But it can be executed, that is the one and only thing that can be done with external `<script>` without browser extensions - i guess. Data is not accessible in no way because `src` is used?

I hope I am wrong because I want to extend my script-loader to load the mime-types that is possible to read. Is there any? Please tell me any/some accessible mime-types to dynamic load externally.

---

**Update** - 
Thank you for answer - Now I conclude:

The pattern `<script type src>` is not useful for any mime-types except Javascript, according to [whatwg.org](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#data-block):

> Setting the attribute to any other value means that the script is a
>   data block, which is not processed. None of the script attributes
>   (except type itself) have any effect on data blocks.

So, setting the `type` to any other value than for Javascript makes `src` having no effect and the `<script>` becomes a *data block* not so useful, because a variable as the only way to put data into it should much better store the data into a `div`.

Never will `type` and `src` work together in `script` (that would open up a security risks), because `import` and `fetch` is already the new way to load files. Script loaders may still be used where E6 import can not load on servers without CORS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not particularly, unless you have a `.json` file and the server sends the appropriate MIME type in the response header. Otherwise, the contents of the `<script>` tag will not be processed.

Per the [WHATWG specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-script-element),

> The type attribute allows customization of the type of script represented:
>
> - Omitting the attribute, setting it to the empty string, or setting it to a JavaScript MIME type essence match, means that the script is a classic script, to be interpreted according to the JavaScript Script top-level production. Classic scripts are affected by the `async` and `defer` attributes, but only when the `src` attribute is set. Authors should omit the `type` attribute instead of redundantly setting it.
> - Setting the attribute to an ASCII case-insensitive match for the string "`module`" means that the script is a module script. If it has a JavaScript MIME type, or if the script is embedded inline, then it will be interpreted as a JavaScript module script according to the JavaScript Module top-level production; if it has a JSON MIME type, then it will be interpreted as a JSON module script. Module scripts are not affected by the `defer` attribute, but are affected by the `async` attribute (regardless of the state of the `src` attribute).
> - Setting the attribute to any other value means that the script is a data block, which is not processed. None of the `script` attributes (except `type` itself) have any effect on data blocks. Authors must use a valid MIME type string that is not a JavaScript MIME type essence match to denote data blocks.

A [JavaScript MIME](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#javascript-mime-type) is defined as any of the following:

- `application/ecmascript`
- `application/javascript`
- `application/x-ecmascript`
- `application/x-javascript`
- `text/ecmascript`
- `text/javascript`
- `text/javascript1.0`
- `text/javascript1.1`
- `text/javascript1.2`
- `text/javascript1.3`
- `text/javascript1.4`
- `text/javascript1.5`
- `text/jscript`
- `text/livescript`
- `text/x-ecmascript`
- `text/x-javascript`

A [JSON MIME](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/#json-mime-type) is defined as

> any MIME type whose subtype ends in "`+json`" or whose essence is "`application/json`" or "`text/json`".

It is important to note that you must use a *valid MIME type* in order to guarantee browsers will never try to process it. Otherwise, future additions to the specification could break your code:

> The requirement that data blocks must be denoted using a valid MIME type string is in place to avoid potential future collisions. If this specification ever adds additional types of script, they will be triggered by setting the `type` attribute to something which is not a MIME type, like how the "module" value denotes module scripts. By using a valid MIME type string now, you ensure that your data block will not ever be reinterpreted as a different script type, even in future user agents.

A valid MIME type is defined by the WHATWG [here](https://mimesniff.spec.whatwg.org/).

Comment: I will read carefully. I have two tabs with JSON that I am not satisfied with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581133/how-can-i-read-a-json-in-the-script-tag-from-javascript and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515141/html-javascript-how-to-access-json-data-loaded-in-a-script-tag-with-src-set

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho What exactly are you asking with regards to those two questions?

Comment: @PauliSudarshanTerho If you're wondering why json imports don't work, I presume that would be because it was [recently added to the WHATWG spec](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/4407), and vendors have yet to implement it.

Comment: I dont see how/if <script type=“application/json” src=“…”> is possible.

Comment: It _will be_, but doesn't seem to be implemented based on the issue trackers linked from the GitHub issue. In the future, it should be possible to do `<script type='application/json'>` or do `import foo from './bar.json';`.

Comment: JSON isn't JavaScript, it's a string. The TLDR of this is you can use a MIME type if you'd like and it will do nothing, but be careful if you're not using one that doesn't already exist, as it may be added to browsers in the future. JSON support will be added at some point.

Comment: it will be `import foo from './bar.json'`. Why get `type` and `src` work together in `script` and make browsers more insecure, when efforts could be on making us use the `import` for fancy things? Maybe they deprecate script the time when import is in every browser, so extending already old stuff I think no more.