# Can you select the script element that included the JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

Is there a way to select the `script` element that included a particular script without giving it a known attribute of any sort?

This example will alert the window object because it's being called in the global context:

```
<script>
  alert(this);
</script>
```

This example wont work as the name of the script could change (for convenience i'm assuming jQuery is included):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/foo/bar/baz.js"></script>
//baz.js
$('[src^="baz.js"]');
```

This example is sub-optimal as it relies on the `id` attribute:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="foo">
  $('#foo');
</script>
```

Comment: you can get all the script tags with `$('script')` but if you don't want to compare to a `SRC` or `ID` then what do you propose to compare? the only thing left is the full source..

Comment: @Greg Guida, I'm not proposing anything here. All I want is to select the script element containing code (local or referenced) that may or may not have been loaded on page load, and which may or may not have consistent attributes. I have fallbacks in mind if it's impossible, but I didn't want to be missing some hidden feature that someone might know about (would be cool if `arguments` could be used in global context.)

Comment: oh, I see what your getting at now. I think the most elegant way of doing this would have to be server side adding `$('[src^="baz.js"]');` for included scripts and `ID` for inline. I get the feeling though, that you want to do this with pure JavaScript =/. If you don't mind me asking what are you trying to do with the script element once you get it?

Comment: @Greg Guida, i had a module pattern that I don't mind sharing: for modules being added to a page (i.e. lightbox), it would be convenient if you could add a couple `classes` or `data-attributes` to the `script` element to specify defaults or default actions. It would be *more* convenient if the `script` element could be selected without needing to *also* add a specific `id` or `class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm hesitant to answer my own question in this case because I don't have an answer that works 100% of the time, but I've ironed out the bugs enough to have a *stable* solution.

@Shef's answer is halfway to what I wanted/needed.

Generic JS Version:

```
function getActiveScript()
{
  var s;
  s=document.getElementsByTagName('script');
  return s[s.length - 1];
}
```

The issue with the above code is that it will select the last script on the page no matter when it was executed. This is a major issue if the calling script was included *after* page load.

As I can't directly select the `script` element (unless another solution presents itself), I'd rather *not* select anything if the script is being added after page load.

### Pure JS Answer:

```
function getActiveScript()
{
  var r,s;
  r = document.readyState;
  if ( r && r != 'complete' )
  {
    s = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    return s.length ? s[s.length - 1] : null;
  }
  return;
}
```

In the new version, `document.readyState` is checked to make sure that the document hasn't finished loading. Additionally on browsers where `document.readyState` isn't used, it will fail out (I can't think of any browsers that **don't** use `document.readyState` these days).

One caveat to this solution is that it *may* be possible to dynamically insert a `script` element into an earlier part of the document, which then gets executed before `document.readyState` is `'complete'`. If the script were to use this code, it could possibly be referencing the wrong `script`. I haven't checked this issue yet. Typically I add new script tags with `document.body.appendChild` (or equivalent in a library), so it's not *that* big an issue to me.

Another possible loophole is if a new script has been appended to `document.body` *before* `getActiveScript` has been called. Again, I haven't tested it, but it may mean that the last selected script evaluates to on that's different than the one being executed.

---

## Actual Usage:

The question was asked of *why* I wanted to select the currently evaluating script element. Although "Because I can" would probably be *understood*, I **did** have a legitimate reason to want to use this feature/functionality/dirty-nasty-hack.

I created a (couple) jQuery plugin(s) to do what I originally wanted.

### jQuery Plugin: jquery.activescript.js

```
(function($){
  "use strict";
  $.activeScript = function(){
    var r;
    r=document.readyState;
    return r && r != 'complete' ? $('script:last') : $();
  };
})(jQuery);
```

### jQuery Plugin: jquery.activescript.plugin.js

<sub>by default works for jQuery UI</sub>

```
(function($){
  "use strict";
  var plugins,d,p,$p;
  d = $.activeScript().data();
  plugins = d.plugins || 'draggable droppable resizable selectable sortable accordion autocomplete button datepicker dialog progressbar slider tabs';
  plugins=plugins.split(' ');
  $(function(){
    while(p=plugins.pop())
    {
      $p=$(d[p+'Selector']);
      if ($p[p])$p[p]();
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

The way you'd use `jquery.activescript.plugin.js` is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.activescript.plugin.js"
  data-draggable-selector=".draggable.default"
  data-droppable-selector=".droppable.default"
  data-resizable-selector=".resizable.default"
  data-selectable-selector=".selectable.default"
  data-sortable-selector=".sortable.default"
  data-accordion-selector=".accordion.default"
  data-autocomplete-selector=".autocomplete.default"
  data-button-selector=".button.default"
  data-datepicker-selector=".datepicker.default"
  data-dialog-selector=".dialog.default"
  data-progressbar-selector=".progressbar.default"
  data-slider-selector=".slider.default"
  data-tabs-selector=".tabs.default"></script>
```

This would allow you to semantically tie in your default plugins to your page without having to muck about in a JS file. If non-defaults are needed, you *should* muck about in a JS file, so I haven't added any mechanism for specifying options (although a few plugins could really use it).

This same basic `activescript` mechanism could be used by standalone plugins to have an easier way of overriding defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your included script:

```
(function($){
    var $current_script = $('script:last');
})(jQuery);
```

JavaScript is a top to bottom language, so, the last script tag being executed will be the current one.

Comment: Unless, of course, you have it wrapped inside a $(document).ready(), no?

Comment: @Shef, very good idea. One issue with that implementation is a dynamically loaded script might not be the last script on the page.

Comment: @Steve Wang: Doesn't matter if it is attached to the ready event. It will always run, because by the time the script will be executed, the script element has been loaded.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Yes, this won't do if the script is loaded dynamically after the page has loaded.

Comment: @Shef -- zzzzBov's point was what I was getting at.

Comment: @Steve Wang: Ahh... I see. Well, in that case, that's obvious. However, you should have much more freedom to pass the just included script element around, since you are the one doing the addition to the DOM in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You could scan the innerHTML of the various scripts, although that won't work too well for included scripts.

```
$('script').filter(function () {
  return this.innerHTML.indexOf('alert(this)')==0;
});
```

Also, this would require you to figure out some string unique to that particular script. Unless, of course, you like using magic numbers and would rather just directly access, say, the fourth script on the page. Which'll just be `$('script')[3]`, due to 0-indexing.