# Inline jQuery; select relative to script tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

This is a bit goofy, as its counter-intuitive to liberating markup of Javascript, however I'm going to ask anyways.

Given this snippet:

```
<p>Hello</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('relative-selector').next('p').hide();
    });
</script>
<p>World</p>
```

This snippet would target the `<script>` tag itself with this "*relative selector*", and `.next('p').hide()` would result in `<p>World</p>` being hidden.

Does there exist a "*relative selector*", or means of targeting the script tag a given snippet resides within?

The answer I'm looking for (*given such one exists*) would not require the use of an `id` attribute, or any such identifying attributes; it would work with an arbitrary number of `<script>` tags in a given document, regardless of position in the DOM tree.

I've seen some strange implementations that don't use `$(document).ready()`, instead relying on the fact that the remaining markup has not loaded, using `$('script:last')` or some such concoction. This isn't what I'm after though; I'd like to `.bind()` some handlers to elements relative to the binding script snippet (*typically after, which is why the unloaded markup trick won't work*)

`$(this)` simply targets the `document` object due to the `ready` handler. `$(this)` outside of load-deferred handlers targets `window`.

I've already nearly accepted that this probably isn't possible, however I'm sure if any solution exists, its floating about in the minds of fellow SO users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you select the script element that included the JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779515/can-you-select-the-script-element-that-included-the-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can probably insert a temporary element using

```
document.write("<div id='temp' style='display: none'></div>")
```

and then using that to find the next element using jQuery. Afterwards you can remove the element.

```
$("#temp").next("p").doSomething();
$("#temp").remove();
```

Another option would be to build on the technique you suggested of the partialy loaded document to retrieve a reference to the tag, but to use it only on load:

```
(function() {
    var thisScript = $('script:last');
    $(function() {
         thisSctipt.next("p").doSomething();
    });
})();
```

Comment: I think your first option is the way to go, I'd use the `document.write` outside of the `$(document).ready` call, so that it definitely writes the `temp` div in the right place.

Comment: Thanks @Antoine - The second version is great; I've been testing with it, however chris5marsh's comment begs the question; are there circumstances under which it would be unreliable? I like the second version, since it operates without DOM manipulation to establish position, however I will opt in favor of the first if it is more reliable. Are scripts executed during progressive page load "blocking", or is there a chance that an immediate next-sibling `<script>` node may sometimes be the target of a previous `'script:last'`?

Comment: To partly answer my last comment, one of the circumstances under which the `'script:last'` version would fail is using Ajax. If an HTML snippet with such inline-relative jQuery were loaded (*and executed*) it would obviously hit the `:last` on the existing page (*likely not the last in the snippet content*) I'm thinking I'll go with your first version now, however I'm still certainly open to other suggestions or cautions you think I should be aware of. Thanks @Antoine!

Comment: Damn, it also appears that the `document.write()` method fails with Ajax; did not realize that (*it overwrites the entire existing page when the inline script executes from the loaded snippet*) This is proving tedious!

Comment: It is a nice suggestion, but sadly doesn't work for XHTML documents: http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#docwrite

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you can make a relative selector for the containing script tag.

There's a jQuery selector for script tags: `script[type*=javascript]`, you could try adding a class or id attribute to the

element(s) you want to hide and then write your jQuery selector to select all

elements right after a script tag and check for each of those

elements if they contain the class indicating they should be hidden.

It's been a while since I've worked with jQuery so you'll have to excuse me, but I cannot provide you with a code sample at this time.