# Is it possible for javascript to refer to the script element which created it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)
>   [Can you select the script element that included the JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779515/can-you-select-the-script-element-that-included-the-javascript)

Is there any `identifyScript` that could make this work? jQuery is cool too.:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="script1">
    function identifyScript(){...}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="script1">
    identifyScript(); //This function would alert "script1"
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="script2">
    identifyScript(); //This function would alert "script2"
</script>
```

Comment: No, that isn't possible directly, though you could use document.write to create an element right after the script that you can target from within the script, as long as it gets ran during the initial page rendering.

Comment: *Why* do you need to do this? Perhaps there is a more direct way of acomplish your objective.

Comment: @missingno, this is one of those features that would just be nice to have. Plugin configuration could move to attributes on the including script.

Comment: @zzzzBov the nail on the head. It would be easy to hand some code off to a client with `<script color="red" message="hello world"></script>`

Comment: @zzzzBov, yes its a duplicate. How do I close?

Comment: @AakilFernandes, the message was automatically generated when I voted to close the question. When there's enough votes it'll automatically be closed with links pointing to the original questions. There's nothing that you need to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as it is guaranteed that the script files are getting loaded sequentially (which means, **not** asyncronously), you can call the following code *within* each javascript file:

```
var scripts        = document.getElementsByTagName( 'script' ),
    lastTag        = scripts[ scripts.length - 1 ];

alert( lastTag.id );
```

However, this concept breaks as soon as there is an `async` or `defer` attribute within those `<script>` elements. Each of these attributes allows the browser to delay the loading of scripts and order is no longer guaranteed.

But if you're loading your files without any *async* flags, this will work just fine because each script accesses the last inserted `<script>` node, which must be the one it was loaded from.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function identifyScript() {
        scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
        alert(scripts[scripts.length - 1].id);
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="script1">
    identifyScript(); //This function would alert "script1"
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="script2">
    identifyScript(); //This function would alert "script2"
</script>
```

This works because at the time it's run in each block, that block is the last one to exist so is the last one in the collection.