# Get the current script tag

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

I wan't implement this configurations options In a script whit this form

```
<script src="x.js" attr1="val1" attr2="val2" attr3="val3"></script>
```

the problem is find the current script tag, and x.js can be in varius paths `fold1/x.js` 
`fold1/fold2/x.js`  `../fold/x.js`  etc... 
I think that is possible  because Dojo framework use this approach.

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779515/can-you-select-the-script-element-that-included-the-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you could safely do this, and not in a DOM-ready mode.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script"),
selfScript = scripts[scripts.length-1];
```

I would suggest that if you can, put any configurations in another script block.

```
<script>
  window.attr1 = 'val1';
  window.attr2 = 'val2';
  window.attr3 = 'val3';
</script>
<script src="x.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's work fine.Is for a script that not use DOM-Ready thanks. All the browser behave in the same way loading the scripts sequentially? or some pararell mode can break this?