# jQuery get reference to calling script tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure the title of question is all right, as well as how much my question is valid.

Here is scenario:

// HTML

```
<script src="/script.js" data-app="app.js" />
```

// script.js

```
$(function () {

  var script = // ???

});
```

Inside the js code, I want to get reference to original  tag, the one who initialized the loading on "/script.js", so I'm able to check the `data-app` attribute.

Is that possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)

Comment: there is a document.scripts property on chrome and IE (for long time), i don't know if its standard (i dont think so) and what browsers support it, but if its for debuggiong purposes and you can control the browser version then its ok to use it instead of bellow proposed $("...") jquery stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('script').last().data('app');
```

Note that this may **not** be in a DOM ready block. The only place where you can access the current script tag is when it executes for the first time. An async callback such as the DOM ready event would not qualify for this. You can simply store the value in a variable though and then use it from inside your event:

```
(function() {
    var app = $('script').last().data('app');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // do stuff
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can enumerate the scripts in `document.scripts` and recognize yours with its `src` property.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a "proper" way to get your tag. However, in theory, when your script runs the corresponding tag should be the last one inserted into the document. So putting code like this into `script.js` works:

```js
var child = document;
while (child && child.localName != "script")
  child = child.lastChild;

if (child)
  alert("My script tag: " + child);
```

You will need to run this code when the script loads and remember the script tag if you need it after the initial load.

Comment: Why not `getElementsByTagName('script')`?

Comment: @ThiefMaster: Performance - why enumerate all scripts in a potentially very large document if you can go directly to the very last element in that document.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.scripts[document.scripts.length-1].src
```

i don't know what browser support it (IE and chrome, yes)

Comment: I think that all browsers support `document.scripts` - but it is a backwards compatibility property, in modern browsers it is exactly the same things as `document.getElementsByTagName("script")`.

Comment: well the last will traverse the DOM.. but with same result i think