# Parse data inside script tag which loaded a certain script

Tags: javascript

Sometimes you see code like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
      {lang:'en', parsetags:'explicit'}
</script>
```

I'd like to know how it's possible to parse the object literal inside this script tag from the loaded script.

Comment: When the script is run search for the last script tag (?), or when the DOM is fully loaded search for the script tag with the src value you want.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script and partially http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var thisScriptTag = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
var data = thisScriptTag.textContent || thisScriptTag.innerText;
alert(data);
```

If you have JSON data you'd use `JSON.parse()` to convert the data to a JavaScript object.
Note that the code must not be wrapped in a DOMready/onload event - it needs to run right when that `<script>` tag is processed.

<sub>The code to get the current script tag was taken from [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)</sub>