# how the linkedin js is a valid javascript

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

LinkedIn Javascript integration is done with:

```
<script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
   api_key: 9XXXXXXX
   authorize: true
</script>
```

What I do not understand, how this is a valid javascript? How come the api_key is not quoted.

Comment: What, where? Show us some code.

Comment: @Utkanos: He did have code in the post, but it was not marked up as code so didn't show up.

Comment: Aha - I'd have edited it if I'd realised. Undoing the downvote...

Answer (score 8):

The body of a script tag with a `src` is never executed. However, the loaded script can access its contents like the contents of any other element. So it's a nice place to store metadata related to the script that was loaded.

Actually, it *was* a nice place for it before `data-` attributes got introduced. Using them would be more appropriate, but the linkedin api is probably older than `data-` attributes or they simply wanted to keep it simple.

A possible way to access the tag is putting the following code in the `.js` file:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
var thisScriptTag = scripts[scripts.length - 1];
```

<sup>[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403967/how-may-i-reference-the-script-tag-that-loaded-the-currently-executing-script)</sup>

You can then use the `textContent` or `innerText` property to access whatever is in the tag.

Comment: That's a really interesting way to access the current script tag--it works because script tags execute in order, correct?