# How does LinkedIn script read the api_key on the script tag?

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api, input-parameters

The [LinkedIn Getting Started](http://developers.linkedin.com/documents/getting-started-javascript-api) page shows the following way to include a javascript file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
   api_key: your_api_key_goes_here
</script>
```

My question is - how can I do this? It would be cool if I could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="helloWorld.js">
   inputParam: Hello World!
</script>
```

and then in helloWorld.js

```
function getParam(name) {
    /* Fill in logic here, but somehow should return "Hello World!" */
}
alert(getParam('inputParam'));
```

Comment: I've never seen that used before - I didn't think anything in a script tag that has the `src` set does anything. Anyways, I'm pretty sure the linkedin JavaScript doesn't have direct access to this - a web server at linkedin processes the request, gets GET parameters, and then serves a dynamic (or static) JS file

Comment: This is the only place that the api_key is actually written on the .html page - and using fiddler you can see that the api_key is not sent on the request to "in.js" - And you know that the api_key is read somewhere - but how I don't know. I am guessing it is via manual DOM access.

Comment: I thought the key and value were automatically sent somehow. But you're quite right - it's not sent in the request. And yeah, it looks like it's being read by the "in.js" script. I'm looking at the "in.js" source to see if I can figure it out. It's not helping that it's a minified file...

Comment: possible duplicate of [how the linkedin js is a valid javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336743/how-the-linkedin-js-is-a-valid-javascript)